# The second draft of our Code of Conduct is available for feedback and review

Tags: discussion, announcements, code-of-conduct

You [provided us with some really helpful feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct) on our first draft attempt to expand our '[Be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)' policy into a formal code of conduct, and we're extremely grateful for your time, patience and insights. This was not an easy discussion to have and we are extremely *proud* of the civility and insight that everyone brought to the table.

We'd also like to thank the folks who took time to provide us with insight off the stage and out of the spotlight through email, in-person interviews, surveys and other research channels. Your voices were positively critical in forming a well-balanced code that aims to represent *all* reasonable needs.

Together, you helped us to form a Code of Conduct that reinforces our expectations of civility, charitable intent, mutual respect for individual feelings *and* the emotional labor that helping strangers entails, and our commitment to always learn and improve.

Please, have a look at the second draft ([Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sgEOl4wP4CIO0rodsplP15_U10bjE3RlMCkA_jI4cMc/edit?usp=sharing)), and tell us what you think.

There are some notes that we'd like everyone to keep in mind:

#### Major changes to the document have settled.

Based on hundreds of hours of feedback (on both your part and our part), we've incorporated all *major* changes that we felt strengthened the document and ensured that it met as many needs as possible. At this point, we're considering all major construction *done* - what we're looking for are things like small sentence tweaks, accidental loopholes, grammar fixes, opportunities for brevity, and similar improvements.

*Any feedback that needs to be evaluated prior to the new CoC being implemented must be posted on or (ideally) prior to Friday, July 27, 2018.*

#### This document is designed to evolve.

Implementation doesn't preclude improvement, it just means that we have to arrive at a point that looks sound enough to test in the real world for a while, and then see what (if anything) needs to be changed.

We will be opening periodic surveys to solicit feedback on the efficacy of the CoC, and will make adjustments based on the results. Similarly, you can suggest improvements to the CoC by creating a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) with the [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct) tag to raise any concern. Please open all discussions *here*, on Meta Stack Exchange, so that everyone interested can find them in one place.

#### Try not to worry, well, not *too* much.

In case you didn't hear us, we're extremely proud of you, and thankful that we've even *gotten* to this point. We want to make sure that we remain a relevant tool that our kids will use one day, and we know that we will.

Teachers have to talk to everyone in the class, even those sitting at the front looking annoyingly over their shoulders at the concealed spit-ball launching arsenal behind them; I learned that in my second year of college.

When you're speaking to something like a code of conduct, you must be ***extremely*** clear, *it applies to everyone*, and we're not making any exceptions.

With that said, we don't expect most folks reading this to find themselves in a precarious place due to enforcement; the worst *most* might expect is seeing a hastily-written comment that was uncharacteristically insensitive removed unceremoniously by a moderator in flag-processing mode.

You're here talking to us *because you care* - these aren't easy conversations to have and *we get that*. You, the folks that put a sincere effort into helping us shape this code *are the people that understand why it's so important to embrace the intent of the document*, and the ones most likely to learn from mistakes, however unlikely they might be.

The need for this stinks, but embracing it sends a strong signal that we care about *everyone* enough to commit to *not being demeaning* and honestly listening to them if they feel like we got that wrong. While that might sound trivial, like something we do *every day*, it's a *major* thing for an online community of this size to achieve.

#### Over to you.

See anything? Let us know. Do you have further questions? Let us know. Please be respectful, try *not* to assume the worst in folks, and keep in mind that having these kinds of problems is also a sign of lots of other stuff going *right* - let's not lose sight of that.

Thank all of you again, so much, for your time and patience here. I'm not sure what yet, but we're going to have some kind of decompression festival once this all gets put in place.

Comment: A common question I've seen: Do you expect anything to change in day-to-day moderation? Is this intended to change behavior, or just codify the rules we already enforce?

Comment: @Undo This just codifies the rules that we already use, moderation is still at the discretion of the individual moderators, and we've clarified that in this revision.

Comment: @TimPost where do you want the feedback? Aside from answers here.

Comment: @YvetteColomb See sentence right above the "Try not to worry, well, not too much." header

Comment: Does the 'no jokes' policy extent to comments as well?

Comment: @Mast considering it is under the global network policy section, Id say it is probably applicable to everything.

Comment: @Dragonrage I'm not sure the SE network gets any welcoming by punishing chatty chat puns with 30 minute chat bans. So I wasn't sure.

Comment: The caution about joking is more strongly linked with jokes that are touching on subjects that are sensitive, @Mast . I've been in many chat discussions and explosions that were centered around someone flagging a joke that was taken out of context... and the problem there isn't the person lacking context, it's that the joke is about something that is a sensitive subject to others and probably better suited to a private chat off site.

Comment: @YvetteColomb What part? The misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mast the sway some people have in meta. A post with no downvotes and then there's one comment, misunderstanding the posts intent and wording it in a way to derail, rather than clarify, and then all the downvotes pour in. I hate it. There's no chance to rectify, clarify or explain. There's a condemning comment and that's it. There's many aspects of meta I really dislike.

Comment: @YvetteColomb If it offers you some comfort... I've been in a similar situation on MSO. My answer was nicely gathering upvotes... then Jon Skeet (himself!) commented and only _appeared_ to disagree. Suddenly it started raining downvotes and no amount of explanation seemed to help. It's indeed not a pleasant thing... but you're not alone, I think many of us have been there at one time or another.

Comment: Why did you put an image in the GitHub PDF instead of a proper PDF file with text in it?

Comment: @S.L.Barth thanks, it does help. Particularly as a user who struggles with meta, it's one time things were going well and then, *bam*. to be completely honest, I find it exhausting. Particularly when people seem to be intent on misunderstanding. A simple clarification can be made of most users, particularly people who've been around a long time. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @Catija: AFAICT, there doesn't exist a good way to establish a private chat off-site via any SE site: Any credentials for one are automatically public, so the "best" result is just changing the location, not handling the eventual fallout.

Comment: @YvetteColomb based on my experience it could help to learn to be prepared and _very_ quickly address any comment that feels like critical (example [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/281807#comment915375_281807), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366665/366750#comment579610_366750) - note the timings). After that, next step would be to _very_ quickly figure when edits can help (but still, combine them with comments). It is especially difficult but still necessary when your post doesn't feel like controversial (your answer here was just like that - I still miss that tolerance note)

Comment: Thanks for the updates, the new one looks much better. I don't get the feeling that we're on our own with help vampires in chat anymore. The "avoid sarcasm" bit can indeed come across as a bit scary, but I take it that's just a suggestion especially towards very new users. Which mostly makes sense, and shouldn't stop regulars from engaging in friendly banter.

Comment: @Mast Puns should be dealt with harsh **pun**ishment.

Comment: Member when [Jeff Atwood called us whiners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74037)? I member. And it wasn't kind or respectful, but **fun** for sure

Comment: @PoGibas a looot of changes have happened since. Jeff gone, Summer of Love...it's a different site now.

Comment: As I [commented on a loss of trust](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312038/wed-like-your-feedback-on-our-new-code-of-conduct/312272#comment1021630_312272) in the last update. I would like to just say that this post (and the changes) feels like a step in the right direction to me - and I hope others. I'm still worried about how it will applied to chat  (see @AndrasDeak comment above) and SE as a whole but the tone of the post and changes made in light of the feedback, really help to reassure about SE's direction.

Comment: *You could Google this in 5 seconds.* Isn't posting a zero-effort question a lot worse than this kind of a response?

Comment: I took the freedom to ask my own question regarding any doubts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312955/does-the-new-code-of-conduct-still-leave-room-for-decent-humor

Comment: While I understand "CoC" is the technical acronym for what we're looking at here, it nearly violates itself. Could we just call it "The Code" or something less ... um ... well just *less*? Just a thought.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I keep thinking [Clash of Clans](http://supercell.com/en/games/clashofclans/) when I see it...

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371410/can-we-have-some-site-approved-canned-comments-to-match-the-new-coc-and-welcomin

Comment: Your examples of Unfriendly and Friendly behavior looks a lot like sugar-coat-your-fingers-before-you-type.

Comment: I always thought your avatar was a pic of a duck wearing a hat or you had a beak, but I just now noticed you are actually drinking from a mug lmao...... anyway, moving on...

Comment: Wait... So not harassing people is still unacceptable behavior? I thought we where suppose to be nice. =P

Comment: Just a few thoughts...  I'd eliminate all the options to close and remove questions, and replace it with a "spam/illegal" button. If the question isn't spam or blatantly illegal, it should stay. If it's a "bad" question, it will simply not attract good responses. There's no obligation to answer a question, but there should also be no right to make a question "Go Away". Additionally, I predict someone is going to take me to task because they don't like this response.

Comment: @PushfPopf You predict correctly. [Broken windows theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory). TL;DR: Having a lot of a bad thing around tends to make people think that bad thing is okay, thus generating more. Cuts both ways - if there are a lot of snarky comments around, you could get the same effect. Aside from the horrendous issues around defining "illegal", dropping question closure would encourage bad questions and drive experts away.

Comment: @PushfPopf: If you want a site that is not Stack Exchange, you are welcome to find one. But Stack Exchange's ability to close and delete bad questions is so deeply embedded that removing that would make the sites into something utterly different. It's not quite on par with a suggestion to have democracy without all the messy voting by members of the public, but it's not far short.

Comment: @Nathan-Tuggy: "deeply embedded" isn't always good. Being snarky a-holes is deeply embedded here. It's been that way since the beginning. I was there. "different" isn't always bad.

Comment: @Undo: "Bad" unanswered questions won't drive anybody away. Mean responses drive people away.  I have this fantasy that people who are having a problem can come here and ask their question as best they can, and get help or at least be benignly ignored.

Comment: @PushfPopf How would you define "illegal questions"? Would you allow Gorilla-vs-Shark questions, or polls? These were made off-topic because they attracted noise, not signal.

Comment: "Assume good faith" seems like a valuable adition

Comment: @s-l-barth: By "Illegal" I mean questions about blatantly illegal activities like "how to better rob a convenience store".

Comment: @PushfPopf Ok, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @PushfPopf While I hangout mainly in Unix&Linux, I am opening more the WorkPlace and less and less travel SE because of the flood of low qualiity repetitive questions. I think it really depends on what audience you want to atract. I also regularly unfollow/mute in Linked.in or twitter accounts with non-work related posts. Not everybody is tolerant to or enjoys a huge noise to info ratio. Time is money. I would say bad content does drive people away.

Comment: Isn't the entire point og the whole exercise "stop the putdown on newbies" - ?  Given that, the whole, entire document should just state:  "No putdowns on newbies."

Comment: @EJoshuaS: As the draft tries to make clear: not everyone knows what terms to google. Being told to google this or that that you didn't even know the name of isn't exactly friendly is it? I think the example in the draft is really nice: “This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here.”

Comment: CoC is super lame.  I'm going to start a competitor website based on EOS, where people can ask/answer for monetized tokens without the mandated coddling.

Comment: In building when you want "No Smoking" you put up a sign "No Smoking".  Why not just add one line of text under the "Comment" button which says "No putdowns on newbs".   That would resolve the entire issue.

Comment: For example, schools in the US today (primary, middle, even high) have an important mandate to "stop bullying" - cool.  They do that by painting signs around the school "No Bullying".  They didn't make a document.

Comment: Even comments that are "borderline" can be insidious over time. Is simply deleting comments enough to show that StackExchange is pro-minorities and pro-respectful discourse? Suspensions create resentments, and leave most users asking themselves "why" and "whatever happened to free speech"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA We anticipate that enforcement is going to look like, for the most part, simply deleting comments where people's enthusiasm got the better of them. The new code of conduct (along with more proactive communication on our part, which will be coming) will hopefully make folks a bit more sensitive to stuff that should be flagged. When moderators observe patterns _over time_, they tend to reach out to users privately to let them know, and only after warnings go ignored are suspensions generally issued. [1/2]

Comment: The handling of stuff once flagged is quite tempered and reasonable, our aim is to help folks develop more empathy for other perspectives that they might not ordinarily consider, which will hopefully result in folks putting a little more thought into their own word selection, and recognizing others that might be problematic, a bit more so than today. [2/2]

Comment: Be careful, people with just an average quota of intelligence will masquerade their bigoted ideas as "constructive criticisms". SE cannot change people's "enthusiasms"

Comment: I'm sure it has been rejected over and over, but if you make someone post a reason for a downvote, much might change.  People would think twice, and they'd have to adhere to the newer guidelines.  When there is a negative vote, others pile on, regardless.  Deducting points for negative votes does not help.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What do you propose then? Who gets to judge in that instance what crosses the line? The mods have always been the ones to do this...

Comment: @Magisch good question. I don't pretend to have the solution, so I don't know. But if someone is a bully, a troll, a bigot, or a racist the condemnation must be swift. They must be aware that they will not enjoy notoriety or reap any benefits by snarkily demeaning people. That condemnation, first and foremost, should come from the community itself, but I'm not seeing it. Flagging is silent but I also understand the necessity for it to be anonymous. So, when I see words of hypocrisy and unfairness, I try to speak out. The mods should not be alone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA All you're doing in that instance then is giving the behavior more visibility. Stack has always been about resolving problems as quietly as possible so as to not introduce noise into the Q/A. By calling out people in comments, you only generate more work for the moderators once everything is slated to be cleaned up so it can be reused later as searchable online ressource, though. I'm not sure how to square these two contradictory targets.

Comment: @Magisch then comments should self-delete after 24 hours.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sounds like an idea for a feature request post if you feel it could be an improvement.

Comment: @Magisch no. You cannot take away a "privilege" once it's been given. Nobody would agree with it. Let me repeat myself, I don't pretend to have the solution. We should basically be kinder to one another, and simply ignore those who drive us up the wall :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm confused. Do you think self deleting comments would be a good idea or no? If you believe they are, then in order to get that implemented, you'll need community support and a feature request. If you believe they'd never do it, then it's kind of futile to suggest anyways.

Comment: @Magisch  So what's *your* proposal? You asked me first, which suggests that you are not entirely convinced by the current system. Or are you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1225/discussion-between-magisch-and-mari-lou-a).

Comment: "Any feedback that needs to be evaluated prior to the new CoC being implemented must be posted on or (ideally) prior to Friday, July 27, 2018." It's August now. Any idea when the next update might be?

Comment: @johnny It's been discussed repeatedly, latest incarnation [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/812149). I have, however, had some positive response when I used a link to idownvotedbecau.se . Most new users ignore these; a very small few edit their question.

Comment: Less is more I think is one of the consensus from some of the discussions I have participated in and opinions floating around.

Comment: *You could Google this in 5 seconds.* Isn't posting a zero-effort question a lot worse than this kind of a response? (@ejoshuas) • **I personally don't think so.** SE has to be a trusted community resource. You can find a lot of questions which could be googled in seconds; instead, you can see them now **upvoted** and revised, while they may be situation-specific, usually...

Comment: I think there needs to be 1 or 2 more examples of common inappropriate behaviour. (And I've never seen anyone complain so harshly about their question being edited, but maybe that's just me.)

Comment: I had no indication this process was even occuring until just today when the code of conduct was published. Of course I personally am not very important, but I'm an example of a large category of users - probably much larger than those actually involved in the process - who had no idea this was going on and may well have reservations and objections.

Comment: @einpoklum: Every time SE makes significant changes there's at least one person with a recognized username who comments to say "I didn't know anything was going to happen!" But this happens even if, as in this case, they had two rounds of posts featured on every site's community bulletin for weeks, and dozens of reacting posts on MSO and MSE, and one or two on most of the other metas I frequent. I'd sincerely like to know (and I'm sure SE would too): how would you recommend improving visibility *more*?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: A problem does not lose its character if it's recurring... it's not reasonable that moderator elections are duly announced to all users, but something much more fundamental like a code of conduct just sort of happens, with little input. This page, for example, was only viewed 11,000 times or so, and if you count distinct users it's probably less than half that.

Comment: @einpoklum: My point is, what do you want SE to do to notify folks more? Literally spam every single inbox to say "hey we are about to change the CoC"? And likewise another 1-3 times a year for other big stuff? It was in the CB box on every site for weeks.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: 1. Yes, of course that's what I expect for code of conduct changes - at least as much spam as for moderator elections. Or rather, every inbox of users with above X reputation. 2. This magnitude of generally-relevant changes doesn't happen even once a year. We're not talking about changing the top bar color from black to white. 3. Oh, come one! There wasn't even a proper side-bar link! SO didn't even _try_ to get people to participate more widely.

Comment: @einpoklum: 1: I don't think it makes anywhere near as much sense to spam inboxes when there's no opportunity to prepare a formal binding vote, no call for nominations, etc. 2: A year or two ago there was the license change (failed). Earlier this year (and still ongoing) there was the big theme shakeup. And so on. 3. There absolutely was a proper side-bar link: the first and second rounds of feedback requests each had their due CB featuring on all sites (visible all pages except /review, chat, and /users) for a week or two.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: All sites or all meta sites? If it's the former then I guess it's my fault, although a week is not enough time. However, something like a code-of-conduct requires, IMO, a referendum with a higher than 50% threshold of approval.

Comment: @einpoklum: All sites, unless I am gravely misremembering. (FWIW, SE does generally pay some attention to community response — see e.g. the license change that got enough pushback to be canceled outright — there's just no directly binding vote, and there probably never will be one, since it's a company, not a non-profit.)

Comment: The CoC has gone live, please use the code-of-conduct and discussion tags if you wish to suggest a change to the code of conduct. Thanks, everyone for your input!

Comment: *"This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network within the scope defined in the help center."* wut

Comment: A code of conduct that does not include the suggestion/rule not to answer questions of dubious quality will not solve the conflicts many sites suffer from.

Comment: Why is this closed as having nothing to do with Stack Exchange? Wouldn't it be better to close it as "can no longer be reproduced"?

Comment: @DonaldDuck It shouldn't be closed at all. Locking, with an appropriate custom message, would be the appropriate action if the point is to stop further discussion in this thread. This is the level of conscientiousness I've come to expect from SO employees in the past few months.

Comment: It was closed with a custom comment, but I forgot those don't carry over obviously when you have a ton of comments, so I'lll re-open and lock this.

Comment: .... and historical significance is even worse, because that also says "this should not be considered a good, on-topic question" which is even _more_ confusing. I'm just going to leave it open until something better comes along.

Answer (score 235):

> *Don't worry if others give feedback about your question -- they’re trying to make it helpful to as many people as possible.*

This needs to be made clearer. It's not a *"don't worry"*, it's a *"be receptive"* (you've used *"be generous"* later on). If people are just not worrying about feedback, questions aren't going to be improved.

> *No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.*

Just no put-downs, no matter how subtle. <s>Perhaps it goes without saying, but I think the CoC should be clear here.</s> It has been pointed out that the Be Nice policy covers this.

> *“Thanks for improving my question. I’m happy to provide any other info you’ll need to answer it.”*

We *really* don't need askers thanking us for every edit we make. It's unnecessary, distracting noise.

> *No bigotry. We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion -- and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.*

This is much better! [The discrimination list from the previous version was too long and impossible to enforce.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312588/252153) This is easier to digest, has clear guidelines which can be enforced and doesn't ooze identity politics.

> *Chat TL;DR;...  Avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online.*

This is a bad rule - chat often has jokes and sarcasm. Taking the jokes out of chat will take the people out. As suggested in the comments perhaps *”Be careful with jokes...”* would make this clearer.

> *"Feedback"*

You've used the word *"feedback"* a lot. It doesn't sound quite right. I imagine you're using it to encompass both positive and negative feedback, but I'm not sure people need to be told to "*Be generous in... accepting feedback"* when that's positive. On the other hand, we probably do need to be told to be generous in giving positive feedback.

---

As an aside, *thank you* for taking the time to really think about what the active members of the community need. Nobody wants this network to fail because all the experienced users ended up alienated. But we also don't want to be missing out on potential experts for silly reasons. I think this new CoC clearly expresses this.

Comment: I prefer the _subtle_ in _no subtle put downs_. The unsubtle ones are easy to deal with, and clearly fall afoul of the entire Be Nice concept. It's the subtle ones that give more trouble since mods often don't feel sure how to deal with them. So mentioning _subtle put downs_ specifically is probably a good idea.

Comment: Would this work? *No (subtle) put-downs*

Comment: I'm with you on the  jokes and sarcasm in chat but I'm a bit afraid it will create a double standard. And we have seen enough *chat is different, chat has no rules, this chat room has their own culture* drama's. But chat still should be a third place were interaction is a bit more *relaxed*? It needs enforceable definitions of what goes and what doesn't go in chat.

Comment: Jokes and sarcasm are a staple of human socializing. Since chat provides are more direct conversation channel between participantes, some exchanges with a more social nature should be expected, especially in chat communities with a set of regulars who know each other. This doesn't mean that **all** types of jokes or sarcasm are acceptable (e.g. racist one clearly aren't), just that this rule is overly strict in the general case. Maybe a qualifier like "avoid jokes and sarcasm if others are likely to misinterpret them" would help.

Comment: I can understand that they included the jokes and sarcasm avoidance because they are problematic because the nonverbal component is missing, it was even known in the Usenet era.  But **a hatred of jokes and sarcasm are an indicator of ideology.** Every dictatorship/ideology persecutes jokes without mercy because laughing undermine the sacredness of the rules. The inability to judge humor with rigid standards makes it so dangerous. So I really hope it is just to avoid fart jokes and snarcasm, it really, really depends on the moderation.

Comment: Instead of ***Avoid***, how about *"**Be careful with** jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online."*

Comment: How about, instead of "negative feedback," you use "___constructive criticism___"?

Comment: `We really don't need askers thanking us for every edit we make. It's unnecessary, distracting noise`, while that's true, i don't think it's such a noise. Furthermore it is not only being polite, it is also amark that the work you did has been acknowledge. Finally I think it can be perceived as rude to just reply to the comment "thanks are noise" to someone. I mean just imagine every time you thanks someone that he would answer that, that doesn't sounds welcoming.

Comment: @jkdev wording that reads "be careful with... sarcasm" feels a bit risky (_oh I was very carefully sarcastic about user123456 dumping their homework at us_). Although I personally appreciate sarcasm I also feel like I can live without it: "Be careful with jokes and _avoid_ sarcasm..."

Comment: I think we're likely to go with "avoid sarcasm, be careful with jokes" .. but nothing is carved in stone yet. We can't take jokes away, a chief complaint is that the site isn't human enough. So we should probably just be more specific that we're afraid of disastrous jokes by just cautioning folks to be careful  .. but we'll see. Thanks for chewing on that, I wasn't quite happy with the wording either.

Comment: I agree 'be receptive' is better than "don't worry." Being receptive is a positive rule, vs don't worry means to ignore something - the wrong message/connotation. For the same reason, it's better to hear "you're welcome" than "no problem." The latter implies the person sloughs you off - ignores you - rather than positively accepts the relationship/work/etc.

Comment: @TimPost Sarcasm and jokes which have the effect of disrespecting people are bad, but TeX SE certainly contains plenty of both and these are not generally the moments which upset people. Can I really not respond to David Carlisle's next artistic masterpiece with a sarcastic comment? What about a sarcastic comment in Welsh? What about ducks? Or are we not allowed to have ducks participating in chat any more?

Comment: Rather than "Don't worry if others give feedback about your question" I'd rather be more active: "Expect others to"....  We should also point out that part of education is learning how to ask questions better.  I'm not sure how to phrase that without being repetitive:  "Expect that others give feedback about your question -- part of learning is learning how to ask questions better." (that sentence is entirely too awkward, but you see where I'm going?)

Comment: @TomLimoncelli that’s a good start. How about “Expect others to give both positive and negative feedback. Be receptive; part of participating on this site is learning how to ask better questions.” This sentence is starting to get a little too long, but again - something along those lines?).

Comment: One problem with the *feedback* is that answers, for example, are a sort of feedback. *Don't worry if someone answers your question...*

Comment: _"No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language."_ should be reduced to just _"no unfriendly language"_. Rationale: anything can be turned into a "subtle put-down", e.g. the whole idea of having a CoC is quite down putting, and very subtly so, IMHO (I thought we are all adults, having a CoC pretty much tells us we're just children who need to be told to follow someone else's rules, or else). Indeed, can it get any subtler than this? Please accept my apologies in advance if this comment offends anyone.

Comment: This code-of-conduct is missing guidelines on voting. Voting is one of the most important aspects. Some are far too ready to downvote questions. Making questions as duplicates when they aren't is another big problem with StackOverflow.

Comment: @DanRandolph I have seen very little evidence that people should downvote less - quite the opposite in fact - people should downvote more; many poor questions receive only 1 or 2 downvotes. The issue of voting is mentioned fairly clearly in the CoC - *"Be generous in both giving and accepting feedback."*  There are areas for improvement - like the unlikelihood of a downvote being removed after an edit, but those are a separate issue, unrelated to the CoC - as are duplicate closures.

Comment: `We really don't need askers thanking us for every edit we make. It's unnecessary, distracting noise` Please and thank-you are not noise, they are the cornerstone of civility. They are certainly worth more than an uptick on a comment. It's a `good thing`.

Comment: `doesn't ooze of identity politics` I agree. My primary concern with the first draft was exactly that statement for that exact reason. I'm much more comfortable with the new version. It's a general rule (i.e. code of conduct) rather than identity politics legalese.

Answer (score 193):

#### Please replace "learning" with "knowledge-sharing"

<sup>(or with something else that doesn't feel like obscuring that Stack Exchange is [about questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - say, "<strike>learning</strike> *site* community").</sup>

> This Code of Conduct helps us build a <strike>learning</strike> knowledge-sharing community...
>
> We’re committed to building a kind, collaborative <strike>learning</strike> knowledge-sharing community

I (and probably vast majority of site visitors) come here for help with our questions. We type our questions into web search which shows links to Stack Exchange pages where we can get answers we're looking for.

If our searches will start showing learning exercises instead of answers, that will be very disappointing. [Quoting self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367319/839601), *I don't want my search results polluted with useless solutions to homework dumps*.

---

Besides above, please consider two relatively minor spelling changes to the text:

> We created this Code of Conduct because it reinforces the respect our community members <strike>expects</strike> *expect* from one another. Also, having <strike>a</strike> *this code* provides us...

---

Also I would like to emphasize concerns regarding word "help" laid out in details in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/312873#312873). In order to address it, please consider replacing this word with "answer":

> to get <strike>help</strike> *answers*...
>
> to <strike>help others</strike> *provide answers*

Since answer referred above appeals to experience of two smaller and rather special sites in the network, it is worth pointing that folks at Stack Overflow appear to [share similar concern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601):

> <sup>The primary purpose is to build a repository of questions and answers. By its very nature, of course, that is going to help people, and that is the rationale behind creating the site... but it is *not* the rationale behind *using* it.</sup>
>
> <sup>If you make the primary purpose "helping people" (with the implicit "at all costs" that goes along with it), and let "build a repository" be the secondary purpose, the secondary purpose *is* going to get forgotten and SO will devolve into a shitty Experts Exchange clone...</sup>

Comment: or knowledge base?. I agree with premise.

Comment: @YvetteColomb "base" would probably be even better but won't blend well with word "community" that follows. That _community_ word probably can be thrown away from the first part I quoted - "This Code of Conduct helps us build a collaborative knowledge base" - but is likely necessary in the second because it appears to focus on "kind" (knowledge base can't be kind:)

Comment: yeh I agree, I wasn't 100% with your or my suggestion. I still gave you an upvote, as the learning needs to be removed. IMO

Comment: Or just entirely scratch the learning? I mean, it's referred to as 'the community' throughout the rest of the document and the second sentence already explains that it's about people asking questions and sharing what they know: *'Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know,'*

Comment: @Tinkeringbell this sounds like a worthy alternative. I tried to imagine how it would read and word community alone feels a bit like missing something but extended to "site community" seems to blend in really well. Maybe even better than first version I proposed, although I haven't yet fully made up my mind on that

Comment: @Tinkeringbell ...I am still not completely sure mind you but your idea really seems too good to be buried in comments so I made an edit to explicitly incorporate it as an option to consider

Comment: That's okay, I thought it wasn't self-sufficient enough to be another answer, so I put it in a comment thinking it would get upvoted enough if enough people liked it to not be buried. But this is an awesome alternative too! :D

Comment: This answer highlights what I see as the main disconnect between power users and neophytes. The former want to define this site as a knowledge resource akin to perhaps WikipidiaDotCom. This group sees poor questions as unwelcoming and hostile.  They want to solve things by improving questions.  The latter see this site as a QnA resource akin to AnswersDotCom and are shocked that their seemingly benign question is met with apparent ire.  As neophytes they likely just never participate again, though if they did they would likely frame respondents as the problem.  There is a huge disconnect here.

Comment: @JonSG interesting that "power users" appear to vastly outnumber "neophytes". For example [traffic stats for Stack Overflow](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic) currently say "9.8m visits/day" - probably from folks like me who are looking for answers, while those who ask make ~1000x(!) less than that: "7.1k questions/day"

Comment: @JonSG, that's an *excellent* point.  I think you should turn that into an answer, actually.  This was an underlying point of [my answer to the original draft](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312206/307622); my answer was addressed somewhat literally in this second revision, but your comment spotlights the exact way in which I *intended* that answer.  This site *is not* about community, and this second draft still ignores that fact.

Comment: I agree with what @Wildcard wrote and even can add [authoritative reference supporting that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/839601) ("Stack Overflow is not a large community...") Not sure if it is _technically_ possible to write CoC text without using word "community" (that's why I kept it in my own answer) but it would be anyway useful to clearly and explicitly state this in a dedicated answer as a part of the feedback. (though it would be at risk of being voted down by "welcome wagon" folks who might feel unhappy seeing stuff like that)

Comment: Can one share knowledge without learning?

Comment: well absolutely yes @Nemo because it is exactly how I myself use knowledge shared by kind folks at Stack Overflow. When I use SO I don't have time to learn something, because I am doing my coding job - I search for concrete questions and get answers to these at SO. When I learn something it happens in another time and I user other resources, much better suited for learning than SO

Comment: ...to me, using Stack Overflow is like driving with GPS device: I arrive at desired place very quickly and precisely but I learn absolutely nothing about places and roads I was driving through (and I drive with GPS a lot because I don't have enough tie to learn every place)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice, or thrice...

Comment: Sometimes the ***learning*** comes from researching the answer to a question, occasionally earning a [necromancer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69332/improve-wording-of-necromancer-and-revival-badges) badge.

Comment: @Rob that certainly happens. However Q&A is generally a poor format for systemic, structured learning. Which is in fact good for me, because I use this network for different purpose (explained in my answer) where it works fairly well and I don't want it to get worse in that. Guess many (most?) folks who make 9.8m visits/day at Stack Overflow also feel that way

Comment: It is very pertinent using getting answers instead of getting help. In Unix and Linux, for instance, we are being assailed by a lot of low quality questions, often one liners. expecting help desk level assistance instead of answers to direct questions. I hope it does not help the same as In travel stack exchange where the noise/ratio scale is pending more to simple and repetitive questions. I used to like that group, I avoid it nowadays.

Comment: Placing focus on the sharer as opposed to the reader seems a little strange to me. It's true that without knowledge you can't have learning, but that's the thing: the entire *point* of sharing knowledge is so others can benefit from it. If you as a sharer don't pick up any of the knowledge that others have shared, that's your own prerogative, but I don't think the site exists to serve you alone, or at least preferentially over the masses who gain knowledge as they stop by every now and then.

Comment: Having said that I now understand the negative connotations that "learning" seems to carry - it's unfortunate, for sure, but I understand the urge to replace it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by "focus on the sharer as opposed to the reader". If you read my answer you'll see that I am not the sharer but reader: I read and use the knowledge shared by others at Stack Overflow (several times a day almost daily for last several years, so it's not like an observation from an occasional passer by)...

Comment: ...as for your mention of the masses, even though I don't feel oblidged to care about anyone but myself, I would nevertheless suggest you pay attention to traffic stats referred in comments above. My understanding is, ~10m visits/day to Stack Overflow, with its almost religious focus on concrete questions and answers (as opposed eg to learning materials) make solid indication of what attracts "masses"

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I completely disagree with your answer. In fact, I loved the idea of calling it a "learning community", because to me, _that_ is what the _spirit_ of StackOverflow is all about. Indeed, the very first badges one gets for asking an answering a question are called "Student" and "Teacher"! Moreover, learning encompasses asking as well as answering: there have been so many times that I have learned something new through _answering_ a question, and I really feel that this aspect of continually improving oneself while helping others is what drives many answerers here...

Comment: ... Some of the most highly upvoted answers on the site are those that _explain_ a concept or an idea really well. To me, "learning" _isn't_ something you can only do by setting aside time, and poring over "learning material" like books and lectures and tutorials; I have learned so much from _comments_ on SO. I feel that changing "learning" to "knowledge-sharing" would be doing a disservice to the spirit of StackOverflow, because good answers should seek to _educate_ and explain the _why_, not simply solve a problem.

Comment: @Praveen I am sorry to hear that you disagree but really I can do nothing about that. My answer is based on the way how I use Stack Overflow for many years already and on how it helps me and on how I want it to stay helpful to me. If it turns into learning site instead of Q&A then I will be very disappointed. When I need to learn something I can find plenty resources elsewhere but when it comes to concrete answers to concrete programming questions, SO is _the_ source and there is nothing like that and it would be sad if this get lost in the name of learning

Comment: I feel like the word "learning" has different connotations to different people, and perhaps that's the issue here. I certainly agree that one of the greatest achievements of SO is that it gives clear and concise solutions to commonly encountered problems, but I perceive those kinds of answers also as a form of learning. I don't think that answering every single homework question is what this site is about, and indeed those are the kinds of questions that often show no research effort, and hence a certain unwillingness to actually learn or understand, instead simply demanding an answer.

Comment: @Praveen the problem is that "learning material" has a very specific structure of providing knowledge, knowledge base on the other hand doesn't follow such structure. If you see the program for computer science, courses for programming and compare them to SO. You will notice that the information contained on SO isn't the kind you will find on those courses.

Comment: While I fully agree with this post, there was a change to the title over at SO earlier this year: "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers". Ignoring the minor grammar mistakes, this is apparently what SO the company wants to roll out. More accurately it should perhaps be "Where kids come with their homework questions", as there's certainly far more of that than of career building. Or to update to the new CoC: "Where nice kids come with their nice homework questions".

Answer (score 101):

> - If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Our community is made possible by volunteers. Don't
>     worry if others give feedback about your question -- they’re trying
>     to make it helpful to as many people as possible.

This bullet point sounds weird to me. Specifically the part where it says

**"Don't worry if...",**

I feel like it would be better if it were written as

**"Don't take offense if others give feedback or edit your question..."**

That sounds more fluid to me and seems to more directly address the people who get upset when they have their question edited or receive feedback on how to edit their question. I don't think people are worried, per se, but more likely annoyed by edits that seem to change their question. And considering we have the following example of an unfriendly comment, I think this wording would more strongly reinforce that we don't want this behavior.

> “I came to get help, not to get my question edited.”

Comment: I prefer the current top answer's point that it should really say, "**Be receptive**" rather than don't worry.

Comment: @Wildcard either would work for me. Be receptive and don't take offense are essentially the same

Comment: Not really.  You can "not take offense" by just ignoring the feedback you get.

Answer (score 85):

One item that popped out to me on the previous one, that is still present in this version:

> ### Our Expectations
>
> ...
>
> - **If you're here to help others, be patient and welcoming.**

I realize that the "welcoming" term was beaten to death on the previous post. This really isn't about that.

The initial clause, "If you're here to help others", makes the rest of the sentence far less meaningful than it should be.

- Some people *are not* here to help others, or at least don't behave as though they are. Should this advice not apply to them? I could easily see a bad actor "rules lawyering" this.
- Should this (particularly "be patient") not apply to people who are seeking help as well?

Ideally, this would be expressed as

- **Be patient and welcoming.**

full stop.

At that point you can clarify what that might mean for different audiences.

Comment: Possibly replace "to help others" with "to share your knowledge"?

Comment: @E.P. Simply "If you're here, be patient and welcoming". If I'm here to gain knowledge, not share it (i.e. most people) then I should still be patient and welcoming.

Comment: Giving context helps to communicate.  This isn't a legal contract.  It's a code of conduct.  Rules lawyers are violating *the entire purpose* of the document.

Comment: @Wildcard: If it's not a legal document, why is it called a "code"? What's more, if the point is to write a document that relies on being interpreted without rules lawyers, what was wrong with Be Nice? A project to clarify and rationalize an existing document that leaves some things unclear or irrational just hasn't gone far enough. "Context" that only serves to *mislead* even some honest readers is the opposite of helpful.

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, I believe that's exactly the point.

Comment: I remember a time when I was on a contract programming job and was released from it because, "I asked too many questions" I've often thought that applied here as well, sometimes when folks (especially newbies to programming) ask questions that fall in the realm of "what we think you should know" or "why haven't you googled it?" there often doesn't seem to be much patience shown and down votes and critical comments appear.

Comment: @Tim, yes.
@ Hank, that... right there, is my biggest complaint with this community. Failure to be inclusive of newbs or questions with seemingly obvious answers alienates people and makes this - otherwise wonderful service - increasingly irrelevant.

Comment: Why be so obtuse and legalistic?  The entire overall document looks like a bunch of people (why?) are pretending they are attorneys writing a contract.  Just state "No putdowns on newbies."  It's no more complicated than saying "Enter password" or "Click here" or any other instructions on a web page.

Answer (score 70):

Thank you for your thoughtful response to all the feedback.

I have some minor wording suggestions:

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Our community is made possible by volunteers. Don't worry if others give feedback about your question -- they’re trying to make it helpful to as many people as possible.

I would respin that "don't worry" language.  Comments *shouldn't* be worrisome; let's not plant the idea that they might be.  Instead, keep it positive (and maybe we can sneak in a bit of guidance).  My suggested changes are in bold:

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Our community is made possible by volunteers. **When people give you feedback**, they’re trying to make your question helpful to as many people as possible.  **The best way to respond to comments is with an edit.**

---

I suggest adding the word in bold here:

> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Learning how to participate in our **worldwide** community can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.

USians outnumber others on the network and we sometimes see people assuming that US norms apply to everybody.  They don't.  Let's spend one word to plant that hint.  (This issue has [come up on The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3216/325) and IPS, among others.)

---

> We take your reports seriously. Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions...

In the draft, "in good faith" is underlined.  Is there supposed to be a link there or is that for emphasis?  You haven't used underlining for emphasis elsewhere, hence my confusion.

---

> We welcome your feedback on this and every other aspect of what we do at Stack Overflow.

*I* know that in this context Stack Overflow is the name of the company that also provides the Stack Exchange network of sites.  But a lot of newcomers might think you mean SO the site.

Comment: "The best way to respond to questions is with an edit." may be confusing (OP's question vs questions others ask the OP in comments?) One alternative might be "You can contribute to the feedback process best by editing your question." I'd use "contribute" instead of "respond" to give a hint that they should share in the goal of making the Q&A helpful to others.

Comment: @Frank I changed "questions" to "comments".  The point here is not to answer comments with more comments.  But if it can't be done succinctly, in a short sentence like this, they'd be better off dropping it here in the CoC.  I just thought we could add a hint here.  If it causes problems, then SE should just punt on that part.

Comment: "The best way to respond to comments is with an edit." Yes, *but*… not by *talking* within an edit, but by *editing to resolve the issue in the post that the comment raises*. This is far from trivial to grasp or explain.

Comment: How about "Respond to comments by editing your question to include the requested information."? The *best* way is editing implies that other ways are also ok (albeit not the "best"). Not nitpicking here, this distinction is relevant because non-native English users, some literal-minded people, and people with certain autistic characteristics can receive confusing signals. (I belong to all three of those to varying extents, by the way.)

Answer (score 62):

I feel like [gnat said it in a more *polite* fashion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312859/175248), but when you talk about this...

> We’re committed to building a kind, collaborative learning community...

...I get *very* antsy.

So I admit that I'm still a part of the "Old Guard".  I'm still very much set on trying to help but my focus as of late has been on curation.  [Because we *still* lack a reliable definition of scope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370486/1079354) on Stack Overflow, my curation efforts genuinely feel like they fly in the face of the goals and objectives of the community team putting this CoC together.

Again, I see the common-sense language in here; we can't tolerate jerks who just wanna be jerks here, which is important to codify.  But hearing that we're building a "learning" community **and seeing that codified *again* in this version of the CoC** tells me that the direction of Stack Overflow is changing.

I'm not a fan of this.

Comment: with regards to my answer being polite, this is because as explained in there I depend on Stack Overflow providing answers to my questions. And this is a fairly strong dependency, so it is in my best interest to politely explain that they possibly risk losing [9.8m visits/day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/312859#comment1024915_312859) by changing direction to one that isn't appealing for folks like me. "I don't want my search results polluted with useless solutions to homework dumps."

Comment: @gnat:  Your intent wasn't completely lost on me.  I think we're beyond the point of being polite about it, and start being forceful.  It's getting increasingly hard to whisper about how we really feel about what's going on when our voices are getting drowned out from those who just didn't really want to be here in the first place.

Comment: The bigger problem here might be who stays to give quality answers. I already stop participating in a group because the majority of questions that are prevalent there nowadays are pretty much low quality questions that in their overwhelming majority could clearly be flagged as duplicates. (and many are). I would pretty much prefer clearer guidelines.

Comment: @gnat I completely agree that search results shouldn't get polluted with homework dumps. But I _don't_ think that homework dumps actually help anyone learn or are indicative of a desire to learn. In that sense, they have no place in a learning community. To be clear, I _don't_ support the idea of hand-holding those who don't show research effort, because they just "want an answer" and aren't really keen on learning (see also my [other comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review#comment1026636_312859)).

Answer (score 60):

First of all, thank you for listening to the community and providing this updated version. It is far superior to the first round, and I am personally pretty happy with the changes.

I see one thing (in addition to some of the other stuff people have already mentioned above) that I still would like to see changed:

> Avoid **jokes** and sarcasm

I understand why this exists, but as others have pointed out this is hard to enforce. Jokes aren't inherently mean spirited. They don't always detract from the question or answer, and humor can go a long way to help deal with a situation that otherwise might be unpleasant.  I think the language here needs to be softened. Perhaps something like this:

> Understand that tone and humor may not translate across cultures or over text. Mean-spirited humor or sarcasm that is directed at other users is never acceptable.

This will distinguish actually mean jokes from replies to answers like:

> Thanks for your help.  I should have noticed that I typo'd a variable name.  Sorry I'm an idiot!

The above response isn't harming anyone, but would run afoul of the current standard.
It would also prevent issues with perfectly reasonable answers that contain harmless jokes like:

```
class Milk()
    def make_milkshake(self):
        print("I'm delicious")
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact I don't think that joke's harmless to everyone. I think the problem is joke's that require tone. This includes all undeclared sarcasm, irony, sardonic, etc.

Comment: You're right, forgot to include a check for lactose intolerance. (See what I did there?)

Comment: This is very important because benevolent humor is -part- of being friendly. So it's self-refuting to ask people to be friendly and stern imho.

Answer (score 55):

Since CoC proposes warning and suspending users for inappropriate comments, consider respective adjustment in software to make this process more transparent. Suggest to show them (deleted) comments that led to punishment, to help them learn what specifically went wrong and what to avoid in the future.

Currently the only way for user to learn is to ask moderator to share deleted comments. This involves moderator load and can't scale.

Related feature request at MSO: [Allow users to view their deleted comments, especially flagged ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371385/839601) (over 300 upvotes).

---

<sub>There are probably many ways how this can be implemented but one that naturally springs to mind is to add to user profile a link to the list of "deleted recent comments", similar to how it is done for [deleted recent posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/165773).</sub>

Comment: posted this answer separately from [my prior one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312859/165773) because it is not about suggestions for changes in CoC text

Comment: I would like for it to be easier for mods to give private (just the user and the mod team) warnings or guidance about specific content, whether it is a comment that is over the line, or an edit, an answer, etc. Often trying to provide that guidance in a comment exacerbates the problem we’re trying to resolve and using chat rooms for this purpose is overkill.

Answer (score 51):

**First a compliment: Much, much better than before!**

I like that it is also now clear that new people are expected to get acquainted with SE/SO. Still I think it can be improved.

*Unacceptable behavior*.

I would still include **Be nice** with a first paragraph. One problem with those "Don't do X" is that it invites rule-lawyering: *But what I did was not X!* even if it violates **Be nice**. Then you have a discussion and drama. Another problem is that you could act mean despite not violating any negative rule (This is a problem with law enforcement; people are very creative to circumvent rules). Third I really would like to have a positive motto instead of negative ones; it reminds us to strive for goodness, not simply avoiding badness.

Instead of *No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language* I would change it into *Avoid subtle put-downs or unfriendly language*. The problem is that, well, subtle is subtle and the judgement of both *subtle* and *unfriendly* is subjective and culture dependent, so you steer very easily into this territority. A friendly reminder is IMHO therefore more effective than giving the idea that it is equivalent to harassing.

*Meta as intermediary is still missing!*

You are going from "Flag content" right to "Contact us". I don't think that it is a wise move because SE/SO has a massive userbase and most conflicts can be resolved in Meta. People and moderators know at best what is expected and are quite aware of the userbase; I witnessed many instances when Meta successfully defused a situation where a more direct approach from less informed supervisors would have escalated the situation.

Overall my impression is: We can live with that, **but it depends dangerously heavily on the quality of the people responsible for the moderation.** If overzealous moderators give people the impression that they need to recheck their words twice, **a [chilling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilling_effect)** occurs (not in the legal sense, but anticipatory obedience) and **people will simply stop giving answers and comments**.

Comment: Upvote for *`Meta as intermediary is still missing!`*

Comment: And upvote for `include Be nice with a first paragraph`. It's still an excellent summary of everything and a catch-all guideline that underscores everything else. The rest of the document elaborates on the definition of nice for this community. This is basically here already in the form of "be kind": maybe promote that to an overall guiding ethos.

Comment: Upvote for _Avoid subtle put-downs or unfriendly language_. Indeed I suggest to change this to _Avoid unfriendly language_, simply because pretty much anything can be turned (claimed to be) into a _subtle put-down_.

Answer (score 48):

## Who arbitrates what is "offensive"? Do not accuse people of being *bigots* without intent.

I have a bit of an issue with this section (emphasis mine):

> No bigotry. We don’t tolerate any language **likely to offend or alienate people** based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion...

While I agree with the sentiment that we shall not intentionally or through recklessness/willful ignorance try to hurt people, a problem may arise when a user says something like...

*"Well, I am offended when you say that! That is a deeply held religious belief of mine, and now you say that there is no evidence that it is true?! How dare you!"*

**The rule is based on the *emotion of the recipient* instead of the *intent and action of the sender***.

The problem is that we are letting the one that claims to be offended to set the rule, and how it should be interpreted. So you can have posters that did not at all **intend** to cause offense, that ended up doing it anyway and get hit by the rule.

With this it becomes so that I can write something that is objectively true and indisputable... say for instance:

> Sainthood and prophecies aside: if we had applied modern legislation, Mother Theresa would have been jailed for taking money from dictators and for horrendously poor hospital routines; Moses would have been a convicted in the ICC as a war criminal; and Mohammad would have been considered a pedophile and convicted of child rape.

...and then get hit by the rule, because those that hold these people in high regard could claim offense.

### Intent and action

All rules must be based on the **intent** and **action** of the one who the rule concerns. Therefore I move that the paragraph be modified to read:

> No bigotry. We do not tolerate any language **[intended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intention) to [discriminate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discriminate)** based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion...

In short: we have to be able to tell the truth, if it is relevant to the issue, and even if it hurts. Moderators can then base their judgment on apparent intent, and — more importantly — on whether the **post** is discriminating rather trying to read minds and guess whether someone will be upset about that or not.

**Of course people shall not be able to use this as a Get Out Of Jail Free Card, and moderators should be allowed to try to suss bad intent in disguise.**

EDIT: To clarify... this rule begins with "No bigotry". So if you are found to break this rule, you are being accused of **being a bigot**. Remember that online, [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is in full effect; we are defined by our **actions**. So just as the cliché "I'm not a racist, **but**..." cannot be used to change the fact that you just made yourself into a racist by acting racist, from the other point of view, you — as a moderator — cannot say "Well, I am not saying you are a bigot... **but** I am taking down your post because it breaks the "No bigotry" rule". When you act upon this rule, you are accusing someone of **being a bigot**, which is a very harsh thing to accuse someone of.

Therefore: since the rule implicitly makes all offenders of this rule be labeled as **bigots**, it must be shown that there was **intent** to be that. That one or more in the audience pipe up and shout "We are offended by that!!" should not be enough to label someone a bigot.

Comment: I think we definitely need to be cautious when the CoC is going to be used against those who act in good faith. Personally either  *likely* or *intended to* carry the same message for me but if the rewording better helps to close possible loopholes by those with bad intention and/or helps moderators to better handle reported CoC infringements I support this slight rewording.

Comment: @rene There is a subtle difference, but a critical one: with the present wording, hurtful truths have to be suppressed. With my suggestion, hurtful truths can be posted. The present wording looks only at the effect, not the intent.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so those subtleties often escape me.  Your explanation makes sense, thanks for that.

Comment: 3+ and 2-. Would the down-voters please comment on what they find problematic with the suggestion so that it can be improved?

Comment: We can't read the mind of the poster, so there is no way for a moderator to know what was intended when we get a flag for rude or inappropriate language. We can however imagine 'likely" reactions to the language and then use our judgement about what sort of action is necessary based on the circumstances. It may be that the poster didn't understand that the language had a loaded meaning and just needs someone to explain how it could be offensive. Offensive language needs to be removed regardless of whether the poster intended to offend.

Comment: @ColleenV You can equally little try to read the mind of a reader and try to figure out if they find it offensive. So unless you are going for "I think it is offensive, therefore it is", both positions have equal weight there. But(!) to smack someone with a rule it is simply not fair to do it on the basis of what **someone else might think**. You have to try to look at what the supoosed offender thought. Otherwise the rule is a minefield for a poster.

Comment: Keep in mind that moderators are elected by the community and should apply the community standards to what is/is not acceptable, so I agree that there could be situations where something gets flagged that isn't really seriously offensive to a lot of people. When that happens we need to have a conversation about where the line is for our communities, not try to write the perfectly worded rule that will work for all situations.

Comment: @ColleenV Rules will always have grey areas, I agree. But I find it inherently flawed that you can get judged for someone else's **opinion** rather than your own intents. Also, with my suggestion, a moderator can at least **ask** the poster "Ok buddy, what gives? Why did you post that remark? We are getting quite a bit of flags for it", while with the present wording, once the flags come the post just has to go.

Comment: We are all expected to abide by community norms, and I think that is what "likely" means in this context. I don't think "likely" means that we judge speech by how one person interprets something. We make these accommodations for other people's views all the time - you probably dress appropriately for work, you might avoid dropping f-bombs around kids, etc. The idea is to be respectful of other folks' sensibilities and if we act in good faith and we communicate with each other there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @ColleenV Well I do think it means just that... that we must try to be a mind-reader when posting something. Also (!) it opens the door for flags with mal-intent; where readers that are simply annoyed with the message can shout down posts they do not like. Moderators must not only protect the audience from posters with bad intent, but also posters from an audience with bad intent.

Comment: That's exactly what we do and there's nothing in this CoC that would prevent us from continuing to do that. If you say something innocently that turns out to be offensive the most likely outcome is that the content gets removed or you're asked to reword it. You don't get suspended just because someone (or a group of someones) targets you because they don't like your writing style. The CoC protects you from harassment as well. In the same vein, saying "No offense intended..." isn't a "say anything you want without consequences" card.

Comment: @ColleenV Then why not chang the wording? It clarifies that what matters is intent and action, and not someone else's notion of what is offensive.

Comment: Because it isn't intent that matters. It's how the community/society you are a part of views what you do. If you think that no-one should find some word offensive, but everyone in the community does find it offensive, you shouldn't use it even though you don't "intend" to be hurtful. It is disruptive to the community whether you intend it to be or not.

Comment: @ColleenV If you are going to **discipline** someone, then intent is **everything**. You cannot beat down on someone and say "You done wrong" if they never had the intent to do so. That is horrendous! Especially so when you are accusing them of being a **bigot**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1220/discussion-between-michaelk-and-colleenv).

Comment: Saying "that phrasing is against the CoC is **not** calling someone a bigot. And "I didn't mean it that way" or "it was supposed to be funny" is not a get-out-of-everything card. People need to think before they type. If what they type bothers people, they will be told to type different things in the future. None of this is about whether the person "is a bigot" or not.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes you are calling someone a bigot. If you have produced bigotry, you are a bigot. So if a moderator says "That post violates the CoC, specifically the 'No Bigotry' rule", the moderator is saying that the post is bigotry. The moderator therefore says that whoever made that post is a bigot. Like I said in the post: "I am not saying you are bigot, but your post is bigotry", that just does not fly. That is an even **weaker** get-out-clause than "I did not intend it that way", because the latter can be valid. But saying "You posted bigotry, but you are not a bigot", cannot.

Comment: I understand that is your position. I just don't agree with it at all. But let me ask: if the heading "No bigotry" was removed, would your objections evaporate?

Comment: @KateGregory Not all of them, no... because I still find that any rule that anyone gets judged by should be based on **intent** and not on result, especially not when the result is based on the whims of other people that are not Stack Exchange appointed moderators.

Comment: @KateGregory I also have a huge problem that this puts a wet blanket over the place in that people will have to tippy-toe when posting; that fact and valid reasoning may be suppressed by a shouting mob, or even single individuals that just do not like the poster and/or the post. [Stack Exchange's mission statement](https://stackexchange.com/tour) is: "This site is all about getting answers". Answers shall not be able to be suppressed just because someone does not **like** the answer, or the answerer. And the rule — in its present wording — allows just that kind of suppression.

Comment: It is unpleasant when someone says "that comment was bigoted and offensive" and removes it. But it is far more unpleasant when someone says "you don't understand this, because you're a woman, but [explanation.]" If it's not possible to write a set of rules that prevents both those cases, I'll go for removing the random and non-useful bigotry, even if that leaves the "I was just trying to help" commenter feeling unjustly accused. That said, I think you can write rules to keep us out of both situations.

Comment: @KateGregory Also the CoC **should** state that bigotry is not accepted. Leaving that bit out is not acceptable in my opinion. So I stand by my suggestion; the wording should be: "No bigotry. We do not tolerate any language **intended to** offend or to alienate people...".

Comment: @KateGregory *"you don't understand this, because you're a woman..."* ....is blatant **intentional** bigotry and would be whacked easily with the wording I have suggested.

Comment: Very well put. The guidelines seems to make no distinction between "offending someone" and "taking offence". The latter is subjective, and honestly cannot be enforced.

Comment: How do you know that Kate’s example is intentional bigotry? You judge it to be offensive, but there are places in the world where women aren’t educated and men are, and that statement could be viewed as matter of fact and stated with no intention to offend. You have to trust other people to be reasonable. Let’s not beat each other up with the rules and trust that if we treat each other well and communicate most of the time things will work out. We use the appeal system for when it doesn’t

Comment: @ColleenV With that comment you do not at all address my concerns. Instead you have now taken to defend the **bigot**. But you and Kate do bring up a good point. I have therefore edited the suggested wording and added the critical part that is the subject of anti-bigotry legislation around the world: **discrimination**. When an argument **discriminates** based on certain demographics, then is when it is actionable.

Comment: Your concern as I understand it is that your behavior will be held to a standard that you either don’t understand or don’t agree with and you don’t think that’s fair. We aren’t writing a law here, we’re trying to agree on how we *should* behave toward each other. I shouldn’t talk to you in a way that disparages you. If I do, the mod team will do something about it. If I act badly egregiously or repeatedly the consequences will be more severe than if I made an innocent mistake. If a mod overreacts I have some recourse.  That is basically all that the CoC is saying.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree that the CoC should regulate behaviour. And for that reason, I think it is behaviour that should be what defines the rule, and not someone else's response to a behaviour. But with the present wording, that is how the rule is written. That if **someone else** reacts badly to what you did, then you have broken the rule. That is wrong.

Comment: I don’t understand why you believe that how someone else reacts to your behavior isn’t the defining factor as to whether your behavior is a problem. The underlying reason for these rules is so that participating on an SE site is a good experience for as many people as possible. If you do something that disrupts the community, you are likely to have some sort of consequence for that regardless of the exact wording of the CoC. Frankly I think the entire policy should be “Be Nice.” similar to GM’s “Dress appropriately.” dress code.

Comment: @ColleenV "I don't understand...". That is not an argument, and certainly not something to bring forth in a discussion like this, where we are discussing the rules for all of Stack Exchange. **All** legislation, all rule-making is made to hold you accountable for **your intentional actions**. Rule-making and legislation is never made to hold you accountable for someone else's subjective opinion of your actions. That is inherently arbitrary and therefore unsuitable, unethical even, to make rules by.

Comment: @ColleenV The reason that it is the intent and not the result that counts is that you have to be able to make a judgement **before** your action if you think it is in compliance with the rule or not. To have a system of rulers where you cannot know that, but you have to wait and see if someone decides to take offense, and thereby making the moderators have to convict you of being a bigot... that is just absurd. The rules are meant to regulate behaviour **before** the action happens, not to slap people around for lulz and retribution after the fact. I say again: intent and action is everything.

Comment: @MichaelK: "*That if someone else reacts badly to what you did, then you have broken the rule. That is wrong.*" OK, so what you're saying is that, so long as the user can manufacture plausible deniability for their statement, then it's fine? That if it is not obviously bigotry, then it must be assumed to be fair game, no matter what? That if someone can argue that it isn't intended as an insult, then it isn't insulting? Sorry, but I'm not buying it. Accidentally causing someone's death is called "manslaughter"; not every crime or rule requires intent.

Comment: @NicolBolas 1) Manslaughter is still an intentional act but that is besides the point; you are talking about **recklessness**. And those crimes also require intent, that you intentionally behaved in a callous and dangerous manner, ignoring the risk you caused. 2) No, not "no matter what", and I specifically pointed that out. I mean that just because someone claims "I feel insulted" does not automatically make it an insult. I choose the example in the post from real world instances where people claim that they have been insulted in a bigotous manner just for hearing things like that.

Comment: @NicolBolas To counter-example: just because I was involved in an incident where someone died, and my actions were part of the events that happened, does not mean I automatically get convicted of murder or manslaughter, or even reckless endangerment that caused grievous bodily harm. Intent is **everything**. When judging accountability, the question is always: as you made you decisions, what was you **intent** with them, and could a [reasonable person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person) assume that these actions would fulfill that intent?

Comment: I’m not arguing with you, I am trying to understand your view. I think that you are conflating the rule wth consequences. Intent is important when determining what the consequences should be for breaking a rule, but you can break a rule even if you are completely ignorant of that rule and had no intention of breaking any rule. The CoC doesn’t judge accountability, people do that. Be nice to people and you shouldn’t have any problems. Mods do consider intent when we see a flag and may choose not to act even if you technically broke a rule. If we’re not being fair the CM team will fix it.

Comment: @ColleenV Ignorance is not an excuse. When you sign up to the site you are also agreeing to follow the CoC and the rules therein. You are **expected** to know the rules, all the rules. That is the agreement you go into with SE when you sign up, and not some absurd "Oh just so you know: we may hit you with some rules you did not know". But that means the rules **have to be knowable**. You must be able to gauge the action you are considering against the rules and make your own judgement first. Otherwise the rules are arbitrary, unfair, and **useless**.

Comment: @ColleenV Also, I am getting very curious: why this insistence on keeping the wording? What is it that you judge to be **better** with that instead of what I have suggested? "Discrimination" is a helluva lot more clearly defined and easy to make a judgement on compared to "likely to cause offense or alienation". The latter requires mind-reading, while "discrimination" can be read out loud from the text itself. If someone writes "women are worse drivers", then that is **easy** to rule on; the poster has discriminated a group of people and made an unfounded statement about them.

Comment: Your suggested wording is ungrammatical, and not all bigoted speech is discriminatory. My college roommate once said “we jooed him down to a better price” and we had to explain to her that was offensive. She had heard it spoken but never knew that it was spelled “jewed” and was a slur. She didn’t intend to be offensive, and she wasn’t discrinating against Jewish people, but we weren’t going to tolerate that sort of language (and we didn’t want our friend going around unknowingly offending people). Her intention affected our reaction to it, but it didn’t change the fact that it was wrong.

Comment: @ColleenV You were right, there was a small grammar error, now fixed. And your anecdote was **clear** discrimination, in that the slur plays into a negative stereotype against a group of people discriminated on their religion. Also you are confusing two different things now: the 1) Code of Conduct for users and 2) the instructions for moderators. Yes, I agree that moderators should edit away slurs and other such discrimination, even if they were unintentional. But that does not necessarily mean that this is [**actionable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cause_of_action) against the user.

Comment: I say again: if you are going to judge someone and say to them "You done wrong, you broke our "No Bigotry" rule.", then the rule **must** be worded so that they knew **clearly** long before the post was made if they were about to break it or not. "Likely to cause offense or alienate people" is more vague than "discriminate", and — as I said above — a wet blanket, where people may be scared and go tippy-toe just because they worry that someone might start flagging their posts and the moderators start handing out warnings or bans when they never had the intent to be bigots!

Comment: Are you saying that a moderator can’t fairly warn or suspend a user unless there is an explicit rule in writing stating what they did was wrong and that it is the offending user’s interpretation of the rules that decides whether or not any rule was broken? I don’t think we’re going to see eye-to-eye on this because you believe that some things are objectively true that I think are just your (valid) interpretation. No amount of word-smithing is going to help if you don’t trust the people in the system to be fair. Trust has to be earned, so I’m not dismissing your concerns. I just don’t agree.

Comment: @ColleenV Half yes that is what I am saying: you cannot **disipline** someone unless they had a fair chance at knowing beforehand if they were going to break the rule or not. Half no, it is not up to the offende**r**'s interpretation. But it is also not up to the offende**d**'s interpretation. UK got slammed for that kind of BS with their libel laws that made it so that someone only needed to claim offense in order to bring charges against someone, even if what was said was perfectly true and relevant. [Thankfully they changed that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defamation_Act_2013).

Comment: @ColleenV And your comment about trusting people is besides the point, because of we could trust people fully, the rules would not be needed. But now the need is apparent, so the rules are being amended. And unless you want to make the situation **worse** the rules have to be as clear, fair and impervious to abuse as possible.The present wording of the  "No Bigotry" rule is not that. It can be made clearer, fairer and less open to abuse, and I believe my suggestion achieves that.

Comment: We're not going to agree on this. Rules are interpreted by the people applying them and if you don't trust those people to be fair, it makes no difference how the rules are written. I prefer "likely to offend" because I don't want to argue with someone over the exact meaning of "to discriminate" and it gives me the flexibility to push back on someone frivolously flagging something as offensive (one person's interpretation of something as "offensive" doesn't rise to the "likely" threshold in my opinion). No user should have to act like a "rules lawyer" to get fair treatment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1222/discussion-between-michaelk-and-colleenv).

Comment: @MichaelK raises the same concern I'd planned to post. If a poster doesn't know X is considered "offensive" (for cultural reasons, language barriers, age, etc), then their use of X can be a teachable moment - exactly as in ColleenV's anecdote. *Either* wording lets mods edit offending text & explain why, so there's little difference. What matters is whether a person intended to be insulting or offensive, because that behavior is less likely to change and will harm the community. "One person's interpretation" is the issue - who decides "likely"? Some people are offended by everything.

Comment: "I don’t understand why you believe that how someone else reacts to your behavior isn’t the defining factor as to whether your behavior is a problem." ... Because we cannot control other people's reactions. SE sites span languages & countries w/distinct cultural norms. There is no way to predict or enforce a rule that accounts for all "likely" *re*actions (which would itself be biased to mods' personal/cultural norms). The only enforceable option is to proscribe *actions*. Question the poster's intent, explain why a comment may be "offensive" and see if/how they adjust their behavior.

Comment: @ColleenV _I don’t understand why you believe that how someone else reacts to your behavior isn’t the defining factor as to whether your behavior is a problem_ I'm sorry to tell you that your comment (and many other comments here) has a very down-putting effect on me, in fact I find many of the things that are being said here quite offensive to my way of thinking & feeling (I truly believe CoCs are not necessary). I acknowledge that the authors probably did not intend to offend me, but so is my reaction, emotionally that is, and I cannot control it. Apologies if my comment is offending anyone.

Comment: This answer is too strong.  For example you could've changed the names to protect the innocent.

Comment: It's interesting that you chose to use an example whose sole raison d'être appears to be that it will be offensive, i.e. it's intentionally offensive. Why else would anybody write this bit of text ever?

Comment: @sgf No, the intent is not offense. That is legitimate critique when someone lifts these people up and holds them as authoritative based on their supposed good character. Well if their *actions* include medical neglect, mass murder and child rape, then that obliterates that argument.

Comment: @MichaelK You seriously consider that text, especially when prefaced with a bit about it being "objectively true and indisputable" to be likely to convince anyone that disagrees with you? Because that's the goal of legitimate critique. And you can make the same points without causing a strong emotional reaction in the readers that will hamper constructive conversation, by choosing words that are less judgmental and offensive, even if you think that the judgmental and offensive words are appropriate.

Comment: Personally, I find it almost impossible to discuss policy on this site without addressing the context in which that occurs and being completely misunderstood as pertains to intent. And yet, all information is context dependent. (+1) for your answer!

Answer (score 39):

I missed the opportunity to give feedback on the last version, but this is a big improvement. There is one aspect I want to point out that I haven't seen in other comments:

With the current presentation, I get the feeling that the code is trying to "sneak" in a thought process we like under the guise of being friendly. I'm particularly thinking of this entry in the Unfriendly/Friendly table:

> I came to get help, not to get my question edited.
>
> ---
>
> Thanks for improving my question. ...

The difference between these statements is not just that one is unfriendly and the other is not. In one case the questioner objects to the edit, in the other they thank for the edit. We want edits to be good, and we want people to accept good edits, but edits are not always good. I think the code of conduct could benefit from acknowledging this and showing a graceful way to point it out. For example:

> Thanks for trying to help, but your edit does not preserve the meaning of my question. I have rolled it back and tried to clarify the question with an edit of my own.

Accepting collaboration in the form of clarifying or generalizing edits is an important part of using SE and should be stated plainly, not be implicitly stated in an example of something else.

Comment: I think there are two issues in this area: OP objections to *good* edits (OPs sometimes seem to take edits as personal affronts), and OP objections to *bad* edits.  The CoC example seems to be envisioning the first kind, but I agree that there is a potential confusion, and the suggested improved response doesn't make sense in the latter scenario.

Answer (score 37):

From the Chat TL;DR:

> **Be kind.** Be polite and friendly with others. <del>Avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online.</del> If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop engaging and move on.

Please don't tell people to categorically avoid jokes and sarcasm in chat. Chat is *full* of jokes—in fact it is *the place* for making jokes, usually—and sarcasm is an ordinary part of conversation. Both of these things are fine. Conveying tone is is difficult, but finding out how to convey jokes well, and handling things when they land poorly, is just part of conversation.

Others have suggested rewording this focus on the difficulty of communication but really, this sentence just needs to be ditched.

Summarise that you shouldn't be a jerk or harass people or something instead here and let people handle poorly executed jokes sensibly like we currently do.

Comment: looks like this is [status-kinda-planned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/312930#comment1025077_312855): _'I think we're likely to go with "avoid sarcasm, be careful with jokes" ..'_

Comment: @gnat That's good news, thanks. 

Comment: Instead of asking people to _"avoid sarcasm, be careful with jokes"_ we should educate members to find the fun of it, perhaps by adding this excellent quote _“There’s a humorous side to every situation. The challenge is to find it.”_ - George Carlin

Comment: @miraculixx I disagree. Sarcasm is difficult to distinguish online, either because it's subtle, or because there is no vocal component. It's much better to say what you mean directly, rather than imply something and hope everyone else catches it.

Answer (score 36):

**I prefer this version to the previous one!** I am glad that the changes made were all positive. I'm also happy that it is now on github. Of course, I still have some feedback, some of which was already echoed by others.

### The main document

> Be generous in both giving and accepting feedback.

**This seems an odd use of the word *generous*.** It reads to me as "be extensive in the quantity and length of feedback you give". Generous, when used as an adjective, means larger than expected. While feedback should be thorough, I don't think it should be *generous*. Instead, perhaps you could use a different and less ambiguous word.

> No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.

**I still strongly dislike this wording.** It is not only too vague to be enforced and extremely subjective, but can be used as an excuse both to troll and to be a backseat mod. Simply telling people to be nice to each other and be respectful encompases this. Unlike many of the other parts of the document, this one is based heavily on subjective opinions rather than intent. Instead, why not tell people to behave professionally in both feedback given and in response to feedback received? That is all we need.

> Avoid jokes and sarcasm

**Avoid jokes? Really?** I can't tell you how much I dislike this. While it is true that tone is difficult to decipher on a text-based communication medium, we should absolutely *not* be told to refrain from making jokes. Instead, why not simply say to avoid making jokes at another's expense, or even to avoid making hurtful jokes? It's unnecessarily redundant to specify sarcasm, since that is already (typically) unfriendly. I've made jokes in some of my comments and answers. I hope I do not have to remove them, despite their benign nature.

### The TL;DR

**I think the tl;dr is too long now**, given that the main document has been trimmed. Perhaps it should keep only the bolded text and either completely drop the rest, or make it significantly shorter. A tl;dr should be short enough that you won't just skim it.

**Have we all forgotten about [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?** The chat tl;dr should not be distinct. The only difference between the two is that the chat rules don't tell you to be patient and welcoming. This is such a minor difference that there is no need to have two separate documents. The fact that it already has the conditional "if you're here to help others" (as opposed to only being here to socialize in chat), there is no need to remove it from the chat document.

### Title of the document

**I propose keeping the name of the Be Nice policy.** I, like many others, dislike the term "Code of Conduct". I have seen too many projects fall into chaos when such things were created. It simply leaves a dirty taste in my mouth. The previous policy was called Be Nice which itself seems more of a friendly reminder that we are all here to learn, and less like an authoritarian document to be (ab)used by moderators and trolls at will.

Comment: I'm reading in order and your summary seems best to indicate my concerns. ty! I wrote above ; Benevolent humor is -part- of being friendly. So it's self-refuting to ask people to be friendly and stern imho.

Comment: I agree with your comments re: "generous". Perhaps "gracious" fits the meaning better?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Perhaps, or maybe "be professional when", or "be polite when".

Comment: "I still strongly dislike this wording...."  Why?  The entire, total point of this whole exercise is to finally stop putdowns on newbies on SO.  "No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language." is perfectly clear.  It should be simpler ("No putdowns on newbies") but that's not going to happen now that there is a committee involved.

Comment: @Fattie I explain why I dislike that wording in the same paragraph. It's too vague to enforce and too easy to abuse.

Comment: @forest - true enough, you did.  Not that it matters but, your view is .. *"Simply telling people to be nice to each other and be respectful encompases this..."*.  I disagree.  You know how corporations have those "mission statements".  I think it was Virgin Airlines who had the fantastic one:  **We sell plane tickets for money**.  At the opposite end of such amazingly direct simplicity, is the current madness of this document in question.  The whole, total, overall problem was just that **on SO, many users were hitting newbs with putdowns.**. That's ALL this is about -  **nothing else**.

Comment: Subsequently, all they have to do is, under the "Submit comment" button, add one line of text in bold letters that ses: NO PUTDOWNS ON NEWBS.   That's **ALL** they have to do.  So, it need only say "No subtle put-downs on newbs" or "No slamming on newbs" or "No purdowns on newbs."  That is ALL they had to do.  You know how in many buildings you'll see a sign ............ "NO SMOKING".  It's just that simple.  The whole concept of a "document" is risible, puerile and whacky.  Anyway!  Cheers.

Comment: @Fattie It would be better if they simply said "be especially patient with people new to the site", rather than their current abusable wording.

Comment: I agree totally with that

Answer (score 33):

## 'Avoid jokes' isn't a good suggestion on a site for human beings

Humour is often an essential part of friendly communication between humans.

Humourless conversation is, for many, unfriendly, alienating, and inhuman.

I understand that jokes are risky, and that you do sometimes have to think twice to consider whether they might be misinterpreted. I could understand a wording along the lines of

> *Be careful* with jokes and sarcasm, especially when interacting with a user you don't know well.

But for all the good intent in the new CoC, 'avoid jokes' really seems like a step in the wrong direction. A site where humour is not allowed will be a site restricted in its level of kindness and friendliness, and may well be less welcoming and less inclusive as a result.

Comment: +1, as someone with a sense of humor I find this rule exclusionary

Answer (score 32):

### What about sites that aren't for "*help*"?

I'm assuming that this code of conduct will be placed on each SE site across the network at `<sitename>.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice`, right? In that case, the wording doesn't make sense for certain sites. It says

> - If you’re here **to get help**, make it as easy as possible for others **to help you**. Our community is made possible by volunteers. Don't worry if others give feedback about your **question** -- they’re trying to make it helpful to as many people as possible.
> - If you’re here **to help others**, be patient and welcoming. Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially if someone is new. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.

Overall, most SE sites are about helping users and sharing knowledge about *topic*. But not all of them. Most notably, both [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) are about sharing and solving recreational puzzles/riddles for fun rather than sharing knowledge about a particular topic.

With that in mind, some of the wording is... awkward. And encourages the wrong behavior. I can't really speak for puzzling, since I don't use that site very much. But there are some things I notice for Code-golf.

> If you’re here **to get help**, make it as easy as possible for others **to help you**.

Code-golf already has a pretty serious issue with new users asking coding-help questions. This wording seems to imply that is appropriate for the site.

> Don't worry if others give feedback about your **question**

Code-golf doesn't have *questions*. [It has challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8355/31716). Similarly on Puzzling, I'd assume they have "Riddles" instead of "Questions".

> If you’re here **to help others**, be patient and welcoming.

For the most part, the majority of users answers <s>questions</s> challenges are there for recreation rather than to help the OP with a particular problem they're having. There are [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) questions, but those are the exception rather than the rule.

Will nitpicks like these be customizable per-site?

Comment: over on puzzling, there are questions about building or solving puzzles and the like, but yeah the majority of them are puzzles to solve. challenges would probably a good word to use on puzzling as well, as riddles are just a specific type of puzzle, and there are many types of puzzles featured on puzzling.

Comment: Good one. On [Hinduism.se], questions asking for help are off-topic. And sentences like "Please help me" will be edited out on SE. Following both will  be a contradiction and both to users.

Comment: possibly "help" can somehow change to "answer" to have it work across all the sites. I checked tour pages at sites you mentioned - both [CG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) say "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions..."

Comment: @gnat Which is something [we desperately want to change](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8351/31716) but SE hasn't let us yet.

Comment: wow, these CG meta discussions make great food for thought. And much of what I've found there seems to apply to Puzzling as well. Still, word answer seems much better fit than help. "Solution" would probably be even more future-proof but I am not sure if it would be okay to use while tour page at CG stays "old-fashioned"

Comment: I usually edit out "please help me"  in Unix&Linux to 1) streamline questions, cutting out fluff 2) Because I think people looking desperate does not look well. 3) Because actually at the end of the day, we are on a technical forum and our main concern is having a DB of answers and questions.

Comment: I think the verbiage here is that "to get help" just means "to get an answer to the question you have" which *all* sites fall under. I agree the language should be clarified/specified.

Answer (score 31):

> @Undo **This just codifies the rules that we already use**, moderation is still at the discretion of the individual moderators, and we've clarified that in this revision. - [Tim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review#comment1024785_312850)

Emphasis mine.

I have to disagree here. This CoC goes above and beyond the current policy and, at least reads as such, is much more harsh than the current policy. Should it be policed to the letter, I can't imagine many users sticking around.

Criticism is no longer acceptable unless you bring it with a feathery touch. Jokes are no longer acceptable at all. Are we still allowed to happily and freely (both as in speech and as in at no cost) share our knowledge?

I don't know what SE has become, but it used to be a community by developers for developers. To share knowledge. We share that knowledge the way a developer does. All the sister sister sites were, initially, about themese that were relevant to developers (professional and hobbyist).

These rules feel like they were made by managers. A document meant to be (politically) correct at any and all times and ignore reality. That's what it *feels* like. And without being able to pinpoint the exact cause or or knowing how to fix it, I'd almost say we got bigger problems at hand. A policy codification isn't going to make SE more welcoming and that was if I remember the main cause for all this.

Comment: We're very likely going to change the text to not suggest avoiding jokes outright, but to be careful with them. And that encapsulates all we want folks to do, be _thoughtful_ in advance of how one might interpret what you say, and be receptive to changing tone if it's pointed out that it's being ill-received. We've had that since 2008, we just didn't really need to define and write it down somewhere until now, in 2018. I know folks feel apprehensive about this, but all I can say is _most_ that would actually take the time to consider the policy wouldn't find themselves on the wrong end of it.

Comment: @TimPost I don't want to have a mandate to be thoughtful because that means I get dinged for writing something perfectly normal that is received as an insult due to cultural differences. For example, a perfectly clear technical explanation can feel like an insult if the receiver thinks that it belittles his intelligence by restating things he already knows (but perhaps didn't communicate).  Politeness and tone are important but secondary to the ability to clearly express intent and details.

Comment: @FUZxxl We _already_ have a mandate to be thoughtful, just through ordinary politeness, and kinda vaguely reinforced by our current be-nice policy. Telling someone something they already know isn't belittling or demeaning in and of itself, but adding "everyone knows you first have to" _could_ be. But if you had the presence of mind to be concerned there, you _probably_ already know that, we just need to reinforce it for the folks that lose sight of that.

Answer (score 30):

I just want to point out two, in my opinion, great improvements:

**1) The examples of *unacceptable behavior***

They are less exaggerated than in the first version and it helps that you show not only what not to say, but also how to do it better.

Still, allow me a little bit of nitpicking (p. 2):

> This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here.

If you wrote that, you might receive a reply that you shouldn't answer in comments. So I suggest this little change:

> This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

**2) Reporting and Enforcement**

It's good that you dropped the part about replying (via comment or chat message), as this would probably have caused more problems. Unacceptable behavior should preferably be handled by moderators.

Comment: yeh I agree that google comment needs to be tweaked it's really open to wide interpretation. I can see it be argued up hill and down dale. *"why was my comment deleted?" or "why was my flag declined?"*

Comment: I would much rather see an answer in a comment than "you could google that."

Comment: @Joshua But users shouldn't answer in the comments, and users should google before asking. So why would you prefer to see an incorrect use of comments, rather than a correct if terse use? I'd totally agree if you said you'd rather see a friendly comment directing the user to the How to Ask page, rather than "you could google that.".

Comment: I have made a comment to that extend a few times. It might have been lost without context but that comment is *not* an answer, because it does not answer the question (admittedly hard to see without the question). It simply gives the OP a set of search terms so he can read up on a concept and then *find* their answer with that improved understanding of what is happening in his code. Actually writing a full answer would have been too long for our format. But I don't mind your suggestion for the change. It's fine either way.

Comment: Sometimes, despite the site's bias for long self-contained answers, the answer someone really needs is "this is what this thing is called, and here's how to find out more about it." It's hard to know what to search for if you don't know what something is called. I don't see what's wrong with posting an answer to that effect, which takes basically the same amount of effort as doing so in a comment

Comment: For unacceptable behavior, I'm still more concerned that "no harassment" is listed as unacceptable. I know everyone knows what you mean... but the double negative really undermines that section.

Answer (score 30):

### The Q&A TL;DR is too long.

The Q&A TL;DR, while shorter than the full version, is still 3/4 of a page long and contains 187 words and seven paragraphs (or two paragraphs and five bullets). It's doubtful that a new person with an urgent drive-by question will read all of that.

Since bringing a problem without suggesting a solution is rude, I'll offer a suggestion: How about just keeping the boldface parts for the TL;DR version?

This is still seven paragraphs (or two paras and five bullets), but it's only 67 words and doesn't look so much like a wall of scolding text.

> #### Welcome to Stack Overflow
>
> We’re committed to building a kind, collaborative learning community. By participating here, you are committing to our Code of Conduct:
>
> - **If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you.**
> - **If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming.**
> - **Be generous in both giving and accepting feedback.**
> - **Be kind.**
> - **[Flag harmful behavior](#reporting-enforcement), whether it’s directed at you or others.**
>
> For more, see our [Code of Conduct](LINK).

Comment: Perhaps, "Be receptive to feedback and be generous when giving feedback."

Comment: Yes, "be receptive" is covered by someone else's answer. I'm just addressing the length of the "TL;DR".

Comment: Maybe also shorten the Chat TL;DR in this way -- just use the headings.

Comment: Or have the tl;dr apply to both chat and the main sites, since the "if" is a conditional. After all, some people might be here just to hang out in chat after a long day at work, not to help or be helped. That "if" already prevents it from being superfluous and allows it to be used for chat as well.

Comment: Either way, a TL;DR is supposed to be **short**. :-)

Comment: Or just delete the TLDR. It seemed redundant to me, almost the same size/space as the main. TLDR is supposed to be to summarize in 1/10 or better compression.

Comment: I agree, the TL;DR sections were far too long.  Either shorten them significantly or just get rid of them.

Comment: This is of course much better than the absurd long document.  Since the entire point of this exercise if to stop putdown on newbs, all you have to do is add under the comment button "No putdowns on newbies."

Answer (score 29):

Maybe it's just me, but **"be generous in both giving and accepting feedback"** doesn't seem quite right.  The most natural meaning of "generous" here is *to give a lot of feedback*, but this is a code of conduct – the more important point is that feedback should be "kind, respectful, clear, and constructive."  And "generosity" in receiving feedback is even less clear.

Thus I'd suggest changing "generous" to ***gracious***,<sup>1</sup> so that the sentence reads:

> Be gracious in both giving and accepting feedback.

To me, encouraging users to be generous in the "leave more feedback" sense seems better suited for individual metas than a global Code of Conduct.  But if I'm off base, another possibility would be to use both words:

> Be gracious and generous in both giving and accepting feedback.

Note that the sentence in question shows up in the CoC, the Q&A, and the Chat sections; I'm recommending updating it everywhere it appears.

---

<sup>HT to Dragonrage for [suggesting this word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review?cb=1#comment1024825_312861), though I'm suggesting it be used in a different location.</sup>

Comment: I think generous or gracious is not the words you are after.... at least from the point of view of a non-English native the former seems....strange, and the latter archaic.

Comment: "Understanding" perhaps?

Comment: I think generous is the intent.

Comment: Generous doesn't really make sense to me though. I don't agree being generous can be part of a CoC - or rather, if it is enforced, it will be a different unwelcoming. I have 5 minutes. I choose: try to answer or not? If I answer and someone else deems I didn't make it verbose/'generous' enough, am I reprimanded? The beauty of SO is the very tiny time requirement.

Answer (score 27):

> **Be kind.** Be [...] friendly with others. [...]

I'm not really sure *friendly* is a suitable word on there. While the CoC follows with some example of friendly *language*, the previous instance of "friendly" might get misunderstood with "greeting" (e.g. "Hi", "Hello") and "salutation" (e.g. "Good morning") in a post, or posting chatty comments to get "friendly", those which we have previously considered them as noise.

However, as of current, I'm not sure if there's a better word choice for this.

Comment: possibly "gracious" as a replacement?

Comment: Yeah, this might be better off without the 'friendly'. I kinda like the 'professional' attitude that's on SE. *I've had people call me 'friend' that I definitely not consider as being a friend.* It's going to give the same problems as 'uncomfortable' in the previous draft: People might think they can be overtly friendly and others that you're not friendly enough, all the while dismissing feedback on that behaviour as 'we're just being friendly!'

Comment: Yes it could be confused.

Answer (score 25):

> No subtle put-downs or unfriendly <del>language</del> **behaviour**

Friendliness is about behaviour. If we're talking about language, that's about civility and politeness. Moderating our words to give the appearance of civility and politeness is fine, but I can have really unfriendly *behaviour* with entirely friendly *language*: see the concept of backhanded compliments. (“Goodness, you're doing much better at using English today.”)

If we're aiming to be a friendly environment, we need to embody that with the behaviour we provide, not just the words we use.

So in the interest of pursuing small sentence tweaks, this is the one I'd suggest.

Comment: I'm kinda torn on this one. On one hand, you are right about it. On the other, the CoC is really only about people interacting through language. Close-Votes and down-votes are included in "behavior" too, and are probably not considered friendly be the owner of the post... but they are necessary. So we will see unfriendly behavior as part of the sites effort to remain productive.

Comment: @nvoigt The 'owner' of a post, by which I assume you mean the post's original author, does not get to decide what counts as friendly, however, so that's not a major issue.  Close votes et al are not unfriendly from the perspective of the network, which is what's important for the network's code of conduct, I think.

Answer (score 21):

It looks good.

Perhaps make a mention:

**Tolerance.** It's important to remember we're a global community, what may be rude in one culture, may be considered direct and useful in another, what may be considered as excessive ingratiation in one culture, may be considered as refined and polite conduct in another. Also for many users English is a second language and sentence structure can sometimes come off as sounding rude. If in doubt clarify, rather than assume the worst.

Comment: I honestly think this is a good and important suggestion that's fairly clear to anyone who is acting in good faith. Maybe it needs some rewording for rule-lawyering, I don't know. Either way, +1.

Comment: Do agree. The rule must be explicit that non English native should do their best to write correct English, but that all should be tolerant in front of syntax errors or spelling mistakes.

Comment: If we all agree that *tolerance* needs to be read as *be tolerant to receiving critique on your own behavior despite that your behavior stems from your own cultural background* instead of *You all need to be tolerant because this is how things work in my culture* I'm fine with adding that mention. In other words: We are more looking to work towards a common acceptable denominator of behavior (and words we use) across all cultures (the "true" SE culture).

Comment: And there are variations even among different generations in a culture. I am the son of a dictatorship. The generations of my parents and my own where of self-made men, the culture and of us being blunt and direct is very different from someone 6-8 years younger than me.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro that is so true. Our current teenagers are almost alien at times to the older members. I'm sure technology has played a role in that.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Well, they are saying they want to be inclusive of minorities.  I am a couple of years of being in the bracket of 1% here. ;-P

Answer (score 21):

This makes me really sad. I've invested so much time in math.SE. It won't feel the same if you adopt this code. It's slightly improved over the first version, but to my mind it's still an essentially totalitarian document. A site that tries to be welcoming by telling people under pain of consequences that they must avoid jokes is a very sad paradox. I hope you'll see how narrow-minded this is at some point and revoke it. Until then, I won't feel all that welcome anymore.

Comment: It seems from most of the answers here that your view on humor is in the majority.

Answer (score 18):

> Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team.

'in good faith' is underlined. Maybe consider changing that to bold? I tried to click it, as I thought it was a link.

All the emphasis is done in bold, and all the links are underlined. That 'in good faith' is the only thing that deviates from it and that bugs me.

> -`[Flag harmful behavior](#reporting-enforcement)`, whether it’s directed at you or others. Every person contributes to creating a respectful community.
>
> For more, see our `[Code of Conduct](LINK)`.

From the Q&A TL;DR and Chat TL;DR: Just pointing out that the links are still missing, you might want to edit those in before you put it live.

---

As for the part on **'jokes and sarcasm':**

Coming from an IPS mod, making a joke underneath a question if you're not the OP is definitely not a good idea, the questions are often about personal stuff and someone joking about that might actually be hurtful. Even then, jokes can also come in the form of mild self-deprecating remarks put in the question, a deliberate funny choice of words... Banning all of them won't work, realizing they might be a bad idea is a good thing though.

Banning jokes from chat (it's in the chat TL;DR as well) won't be received enthusiastically either. But seeing a room where people are constantly aiming jokes at each other, and the jokes being about the other person itself, might make new users feel hesitant to participate in fear of being ridiculed.

It might be good to focus on jokes *directed at a person or the situation they're in*. A general play on words, or funny cat picture shouldn't be banned. Jokes directed at people or groups of people might do a lot of harm though. So, I think the use of the word 'jokes' is a little too broad here, and I'd suggest narrowing that down a little to avoid people thinking there's no fun allowed on SE!

Comment: How about just _no hurtful jokes_?

Comment: Banning funny cat pictures might make chatrooms actually useful.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, of course. That differs per room though, there's rooms very strict on usefulness that don't allow any off-topic conversation, and there's rooms that don't mind being a meeting place for community members and having fun when there's no business to be done. If there's not much to discuss with regards to posts on main/meta, a chatroom can get pretty deserted if you're only allowed to talk about that. Better to allow people to have fun and be there when there's business, than having them never visiting chat because there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 18):

> Regardless of intent, this behavior can have a significant negative impact on others.

Consider more plain language: "Even if you don't intend it, people can take this kind of language very personally."

(I actually think this statement is super important. So much of the arguing over "unwelcoming" behaviour seems to boil down to "But when I say X, I'm not intending to be a dick, I'm just saying X. People shouldn't be so sensitive.")

Consider expanding, "..., especially when their cultural background is different to yours."

> “I came to get help, not to get my question edited.”

The "friendly" version of this comes off weird and passive-aggressive to me.

> “Thanks for improving my question. I’m happy to provide any other info you’ll need to answer it.”

Suggestion that partially preserves intent:

> "Thanks for the edit - I realise it was a bit unclear before."

### Unacceptable behaviour

> Unacceptable Behavior
>
> No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language...

It seems slightly incorrect to start these bullet points as "No X" under the rubric "Unacceptable". The unacceptable behaviour here is the subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.

### Culture

I'm surprised there's no direct reference to the number of different cultures using this same site. I'm sure that part of the problem is American users believing the site to be "American culture by default", and I think it would be worth directly addressing that. Even if just half a sentence, "people from many countries", or whatever.

Comment: I don't think culture is relevant. If someone is assuming people are from the same culture they are, they are just making a mistake. That should be on different than assuming someone is using the same toolchain or operating system that they are. It should not be part of a code of conduct.

Comment: I think you can make a similar argument about almost anything in the code of conduct: "People shouldn't need to be told to be nice, they should just be nice".

Comment: If I incorrectly assume that everyone knows what building codes I have to follow on DIY, I am not being rude, but I am failing to communicate effectively (by leaving out relevant information). I should be reminded that not everyone lives where I live in the document explaining how to ask good questions and what information to provide, not the document explaining how not to be a jerk.

Comment: Interesting, I feel that your examples support my argument, not yours. Pointing out that people work with different toolchains, operating systems, building codes - yes, these belong in the "how to ask a good question" area. Pointing out that people have different cultural assumptions and interpret English differently and therefore to be extra careful how you phrase things? That's Code of Conduct. (IMHO).

Comment: I can imagine that someone might make a joke that is acceptable in their culture but considered rude in another culture (many people in Japan are not offended by being called "slant eyed" and sometimes use it as a joke, but Japanese Americans, for example, would be highly offended), but that would already fall under other areas of the document. I cannot think of any likely situation where a cultural difference will lead to someone being rude simply by assuming that everyone shares the same culture without violating another area of the code as well.

Comment: Cool. FYI, that's known as an "argument from incredulity".

Comment: What? I am not making an argument here, just stating that _I_ cannot think of any such situation. I'm not trying to imply that such situations cannot exist, just that, if they do, I am ignorant of them. I hope it didn't come off the wrong way.

Comment: When I think of assumptions regarding culture causing problems, I think of things like leaving out important details in their question (or answer) and wasting people's time, in which case I do not see how it would be classified as being rude. What sort of problems were you thinking of that would be? I genuinely want to know to further my understanding, I am not trying to imply that they do not exist.

Comment: @forest, how about someone from the US who insists that "black African" means African-American and does not include black citizens of countries in Africa? That's a pretty extreme example of cultural blindness resulting in being rude to a billion people, but [entirely genuine](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/31730/7717).

Comment: I totally support adding "people from many countries".  There's entirely too much assumption of cultural homogeneity here, while users are far from that..

Answer (score 18):

**This is a tremendous improvement. Thank you for listening to our feedback!**

I saw some serious issues with the last draft, I like the current one. The following are things that maybe can be improved further. If not, I'm happy with it as it stands.

---

> This Code of Conduct helps us build a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

We are not actually a learning community. We offer no structured learning here. You cannot learn how to program by just going on StackOverflow and start reading. Sure, we all hope people learn from what they read here, but that's a byproduct of getting a solution to a problem.

Maybe just omit it? It doesn't lose any of it's message:

> This Code of Conduct helps us build a community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.

(same goes for the sentence at the bottom : "Thank you for working with us to build a kind, collaborative, and respectful learning community. ". Just omit the "learning".)

---

> where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of **expertise** or identity

This sounds great... but it's simply not true. There is no way to participate on Stack Overflow for example, if you cannot program (in whatever language on whatever level, but *zero* just doesn't work). Sure the site works, you can click all the buttons and write text but it will get you nowhere. A site for "professionals and enthusiasts" means you will need to be one of them or options for participation will be close to nil. I don't know what you meant to say, maybe "education" would be a better word? I don't care where somebody learned to program or if they are right in the middle. Was that what you meant?

---

> Don't worry if others give feedback about your question -- they’re trying to make it helpful to as many people as possible

"Don't worry" sounds a little off here. Maybe something long the lines of:

> Be open for feedback about your question -- we are trying to make it helpful to as many people as possible

---

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. [...]
>
> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. [...]

I'd say just skip the conditions. They don't do anything really.

> Make it as easy as possible for others to help you. [...]
>
> Be patient and welcoming. [...]

---

> “I think you’re asking how to add a swap after system installation. Is that correct?”

That makes it sounds like the unfriendly version was just flat out wrong. Assuming it isn't and it really *is* hard to understand to a point where one cannot make sense of it:

> I have problems understanding your English. It is unclear to me what you are asking. Could you please edit your question to be easier to read?"

---

> “Thanks for improving my question. I’m happy to provide any other info you’ll need to answer it.”

To me this sounds... uhm... dishonest or sarcastic. Again it's not actually on the same level in regards to the *meaning* of the comment. If you did not like the edit that was made, there should be nice ways to disapprove.

> Thanks for trying to improve my question. Your edit wasn't exactly what I intended but I guess that means my original text was hard to understand. I have edited it again to clarify what I meant.

---

> Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team.

That sentence sounds like it's a patchwork of words. Especially the "good faith" part seems tagged on later. I agree with the meaning, but the wording seems awkward to me. But maybe that's just me. I did not come up with any better suggestions either. Native speakers to the rescue?

---

as for the two different TL;DRs:

It seems as if in chat people don't need to be helpful and patient or make it easy to help them. That does not make sense to me. Just use the same TL;DR for both please. Especially since comments can be moved to chat, having two sets of rules would be weird.

---

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate

Please replace that with

> We don’t tolerate any language **intended** to offend or alienate

While that leaves us with a very vague mind reading ability of moderators to tell me whether I *intended* something, I think it's better than asking the perceived victim. The moderators should be a relatively neutral third party. Asking either the victim or the perp if the crime was a crime is pointless. That takes a third party to find out.

Comment: +1 The phrases you point out at the start read to me like traps, setting people up with incorrect expectations about how the sites work in practice. I also agree that the "system installation" and "thanks" bad/good examples seem suboptimal — in fact they give me the creeps a bit. In this tabular format they're presented like they mean "if you want to say A, say B instead" but B doesn't express what's going on in A at all. Especially the "thanks" — what if I *am* frustrated by edits? This is telling me to put on a facade of being grateful for them, and that would just be disingenuous of me.

Comment: What would happen when in the *where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise or identity*  you leave the *expertise* in but replace *all people* with *professionals and/or enthusiasts*? You use that words yourself to explain who the sites are for. And  *professionals and/or enthusiasts* still covers for all sites.

Comment: I also agree on the use of *intended* in your last example. it is also proposed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312953/158100

Answer (score 16):

> Unacceptable Behavior

I am in agreeance with most of the examples in this section the only one I do not agree with is stating "You could Google this in 5 seconds". I do not see this as a subtle put-down. More of a reminder that the question should be googled first before asking a question here as very often if not most often an answer has already been provided. That said the rest of this section I agree with.

> Welcome to Stack Overflow

"Don't worry if others give feedback about your question". This seams broad to me and maybe needs to be more specific. Not all feedback is constructive so maybe reword this to be more specific to the type of feedback. "Don't take constructive feedback the wrong way - - The commenter is just trying to help you improve your post." For the most part the rest of this section is clear and acceptable IMO.

> Avoid jokes and sarcasm

One final note that applies to all sections of conduct is the portion about jokes. Jokes and Sarcasm are simply a tone of levity that is part of the Q/A and chat culture we participate in. I think it better to say "No bigoted/raciest/sexist jokes/sarcasm" As many jokes and sarcastic remarks can be fun for all and not abusive in the least. So instead of avoiding all jokes/sarcasm we should avoid the harmful kind. I don't know about you but I don't want to participate in a chat that is dryer than the prohibition. That was a joke (though not the best one I have made). It hurts no one it is not targeted at a person but serves to point out that under this rule the chat would be rather boring and people would eventually leave.

I am not sure if the `For more, see our [Code of Conduct](LINK).` link in this document is meant to be broken at the moment as I was wanting to read up on the full post and not just the TL;DR. It is not a big deal but wanted to point it out just in case it needed to actually be a valid link.

Comment: You indirectly say it is [google, not Google, as a verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/google#Verb_2) (*"You could google this in 5 seconds."*). Perhaps make that more clear in your answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's just a quote from the doc's. I will correct the case. It is not unclear to anyone I am sure. We all know what Google is.

Comment: "the only one I do not agree with is stating "You could Google this in 5 seconds"". The problem is a lot of the time people tell someone to "just google it" they would have happily done it if they only knew what to google. The draft has an example that transforms an almost useless "just google it" to the very useful and friendly (but still not doing the homework for anyone) “This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here.”

Comment: @ErikI Any time I have said to google it I have provided a link that was simply googling the OPs question title. That said I still don't see a comment that says "Google it" as a put down of any kind and that was the point of my statement on this portion of the CoC. It may not be helpful but it is still not a put-down. Just a reminder to google it.

Answer (score 14):

I have some doubts and concerns regarding *Chat TL;DR*.

I agree with Tim's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312855/357396) about using feedback word heavily in the document.

> *Chat TL;DR*:
>
> Be generous in both giving and accepting feedback. Feedback is a healthy part of our culture. Good feedback is kind, respectful, clear and constructive. Be open to receiving feedback.

I understand feedback when it's used in the context of Q&A. But I don't know what kind of feedback do we get on Chat? I thought it is for discussion about the main & meta sites but in a bit informal way. I mostly visit chat for having fun time and get refreshed from meta discussions and main site question and answers.

> Be kind. Be polite and friendly with others. *Avoid jokes and sarcasm* -- tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop engaging and move on.

I can understand about sarcasm which might hurt users in *some* situations. But what about jokes? There are thousands of jokes shared between users. There are chat rooms dedicated for funny gifs. So, is saying to avoid jokes a barrier for having fun? I think this would not give a very good result in bringing new users to chat. Users visiting chat may feel it is also a serious place like Meta or main. In reality, they are quite opposite. People are fun loving and jovial. Asking them to be careful while being sarcastic is fine (which will be done by moderators anyway) but adding a line to avoid sarcasm and jokes in a policy which all should be bound *could* bring a hesitation in new users.

Our chat rooms are bit different than other platforms. This already creates some confusion when used for the first time. Using misleading info (about avoiding jokes and sarcasm) and serious guidelines could make the chat experience bad. The wording can be improved in this section.

Comment: I guess feedback in chat can be in the form of 'Oh hey, instead of pinging a moderator, it's generally better if you raise a flag', 'Would you mind and take the Markdown experiments to the Sandbox so the discussion can continue?', that kind of stuff. Also, comments on a post may be moved to chat, generally moving the feedback process there as well.

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, what this document might not cover is the underlying different expectations of the diverse communities of users.

We have here many cultures, generations, sensitivities and several walks of life mixed here, and over time, I only have seen a one-size-fits all culture.

It all boils down to expectations. We have visiting here such groups as people coming here with the expectations:

- advanced professionals coming here expecting to share their views and grow with other professionals
- to teach
- to learn
- expecting to have help desk services with elementary stuff
- expecting that we write their questions for them
- hoping to have consulting in scenarios too complex for we to evaluate
- asking us to do their own work/home work/take ownership of their own problems
- validate/approve their actions
- dropping out of topic questions in certain groups because they known knowledgeable people is hanging there
- and lastly, we have the expectations of the own Stack Overflow team.

Ultimately, it is not always easy to coordinate or find common ground on such disparate objectives.

Whilst often I get the impression there is a wish to impose a policy of "there are no bad questions", obviously at the end of the day, some roles that are expected of us from some of those groups cannot and won´t be assumed.

But most importantly of all, *I often feel the CoC does not address this* and is only concerned with feelings.

PS. As for myself, I have come here to grow as a professional, I come here often to learn and unreel from work, and I often feel I am not here to do help desk work (for free), but to share my knowledge.

Comment: The CoC isn't about quality. Low quality content doesn't make it OK to be rude. Quality requirements still exist. There **is** such a thing as a poorly asked or off topic question - that hasn't changed. What we need is for users to treat everyone respectfully, regardless of the quality of their posts. And, I would argue that the CoC *does* address this to an extent, particularly when asking users to take feedback on their posts as an attempt to help, rather than criticism.

Comment: @Catija Many people does not understand you can be lacking on respect to other people **while not being rude**

Comment: There's a difference between "being respectful" and "respecting" someone. "Respecting" someone implies that you look up to them. "Being respectful" means you treat them fairly. They're two different things. Disagreement and constructive criticism is not treating someone with disrespect, it's an attempt to help them improve. As the CoC says: ***Be generous in both giving and accepting feedback.** Feedback is a healthy part of our culture. Good feedback is kind, respectful, clear and constructive. Be open to receiving feedback.*

Comment: Well, one thing is, I accord everyone with repect..until they show otherwise.  Unfortunately, by the time I have read even the title of some questions, the OP has already lost that respect.  If I open the question and find a no-effort homework dump, there is next-to-no respect;(

Answer (score 14):

I understand the limits of suggestions you prefer to be offered for this final revision:

> At this point, we're considering all major construction done - what we're looking for are things like small sentence tweaks, accidental loopholes, grammar fixes, opportunities for brevity, and similar improvements.

- R7-V2 has some links and includes the word "help" 14 times, but offers no link to the help pages. A short mention of the [Hamburger](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) along with generic FAQs would show thoughtfulness and concern that the visitor has a productive and enjoyable experience, so they have a positive experience and feel encouraged to return.

  Sometimes we see frustration for everyone when there's a misunderstanding of what is expected, indeed such past experiences may have led to several revisions of these rules of conduct.
- In the section titled "**Our Expectations**" there is no mention that a well researched question is easier to provide the best answers for and often generates the most interest and best response. The *wrong* way to explain that would be to demand sensible on-topic questions that require more than a minute of search to find the answer.

  It can be helpful to mention that each community can have a different help file, and an additional one for their Meta. Each community represents a friendly welcoming group whom doesn't necessarily do things the same way as another Stack Exchange site. Have a look at our tour page, join and ask or answer a question. The *wrong* way to explain that would be mention that there's no lifeguard on duty: Look before you leap.
- Once people read the expectations and are clear about what they should do it would be useful to direct them to a "Getting Started" document that explains how including some information in the Profile can be useful to the askers and answerers.

  Suggest that they might want to get started by doing X,Y, and Z; more information here ...

The **short version**:

Add:

- Visit the help pages for more details.

  Here's an example of one flavor of help: [Interpersonal Skills - beta (Help Center)](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help).

- Go here next, to get started.

  Here's a getting started Q&A: [How should new users get started with Skeptics?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-should-new-users-get-started-with-skeptics/2545?sgp=2#2545)

Comment: +1 For the observations and commentary about up-front attention to formulating good questions.  It really is rather central to our expectations that people asking questions will perform their due diligence, so it is surprising not to see even a passing mention of that.

Answer (score 14):

I may have missed it, but an improvement could be to add a link to help/how-to-ask in the first sentence, something like:

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. See $SiteHowToAsk$ for advice.

Answer (score 13):

## Unacceptable Behavior

For the third bullet point, how about...

> No bigotry. We don’t tolerate any language ***meant to*** offend or alienate people based on ***things such as*** race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion.

This includes three changes:

**1. *"Meant to offend or alienate"* would replace the vague and open-ended *"Likely to offend or alienate."***

It's often hard for well-meaning and respectful individuals to predict what is "likely" to offend or alienate, especially when dealing with different cultures from around the world. People should be careful -- but they shouldn't be treated like bigots if they make an honest mistake.

**2. *"When in doubt, just don't"* would be removed.**

Guidelines like "When in doubt, just don't" are for people who don't mean harm, but are just not being careful enough. That's different from actual bigotry, which surely belongs under Unacceptable Behavior.

**3. *"Things such as"* would substitute for *"and those are just a few examples."***

Simpler, more succinct, and more readable.

And I think the phrasing *"things such as race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion"* is just flexible enough to include types of bigotry not on the list, yet limited enough so people cannot stretch it to cover whatever they want.

Comment: The flip side of "*People shouldn't be treated like bigots if they make a simple mistake*" is that when someone makes a simple mistake and someone else gently points it out in a comment, the ideal result is that the first person rephrases. Putting the emphasis on intention increases the potential for a long comment thread arguing "That's not what I meant" vs "But that's how it comes across to me".

Comment: Disagree on the first bit exactly for what Peter Taylor wrote: "But I didn't mean it like that!" is an all too common excuse for offensive behaviour. You're right that people can and will make honest mistakes, but if they're honest mistakes, and acted upon by others in a manner compatible with the COC (so no jumping to name calling!), there should not be any harm.

Comment: I appreciate the intent here, but judging people's intent can go counter "assume good faith".

Comment: One way to judge people's intent is to see how they respond to "You unintentionally offended someone" -- people who posted in good faith are likely to apologize, back down, and/or remove their offending remarks. Not always, but as a general rule. Let's cut people some slack and give them a chance to reverse themselves.

Answer (score 12):

I'm still not comfortable with some of the things that this implies are unfriendly/rude. For example, "you could Google this in 5 seconds." I have a separate Meta post [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371347/what-if-they-could-google-their-question-in-5-seconds) discussing that particular example.

It's a little less clear in the revision, but the first draft strongly implied that you could be suspended for comments like that. The new code also seems to imply the same thing (I could be wrong, though).

If the moderators are going to start handing out suspensions for *calling* people lazy, are they going to hand out for actually *being* lazy, too?

Personally, I only recall one case where someone was actually suspended for blatant laziness, and that was on Math SE where someone had a pattern of being a help vampire that dated back at least 5 years.

The [original announcement of the creation of the suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) specifically mentions being a help vampire as a suspendable offense, but it doesn't seem to happen very often (correct me if I'm wrong).

**TL;DR** If put-downs are going to be suspendable offenses, can we start suspending more help vampires too?

Comment: The question ban system is essentially a suspension for askers with a history of unclear or poorly received questions, though. Regarding the "Google it" comments, you could certainly be suspended for it, but that would only usually happen if there's a pattern of you doing that, and you haven't responded positively to any mod messages letting you know where you're going wrong. One inappropriate comment usually won't get you a suspension, just like one poor question won't get you a q-ban... but a pattern of problems might.

Comment: You can't say "help vampire" on SE because it's offensive to hemavores and discriminatory against nocturnal lifestyles!

Answer (score 11):

> TL;DR:

What does this mean?

Perhaps I could find out by Googling for 5 seconds, but my point is that this sort of internet slang should not be included in any official document that new users may not understand because of language or (in my case) age or culture. There's no reason to do it. Use clear standard English that everyone can understand, and by doing so you will set a standard that encourages new users to express themselves in this way too.

> --

And as a minor point, SE uses the utf-8 character set for its HTML pages, so there’s no need to use ASCII from the last century. You can use proper typography in the documentation:

> —

Comment: What would a better alternative for TL;DR;? I didn't even consider it to be part of the CoC.  And I don't understand your last point. Where is ASCII from the last century used?

Comment: @rene — Wikipedia tells me that TL;DR; means "too long; didn't read". I assume that this is used when the author is obliged to write an extensive account of something and is apologizing for the length or warning the reader. In these circumstances (which I often encounter in my answers on SE Biology) I use "Brief Summary" followed by "Detailed Account/Answer/Explanation". One problem for me with TL;DR; is that it does not conform to acronyms I am familiar with (e.g. RTFM) because of the punctuation marks, which I can't read aloud.

Comment: "TL;DR" isn't, as far as I can tell, actually part of the CoC in any way. It's just used to mark the sections off within the PDF form, so it only needs to be understood by Meta regulars.

Comment: " Use clear standard English that everyone can understand" <-- Not actually a thing.  Many people have to work to understand said communications and deciding what the common ground everyone is going to work to is a continual process.  TL;DR makes the text more accessible to the vast majority of users, with a language barrier to some of them.  That's a trade off that's worth measuring rather than dismissing out of hand.

Comment: Agree - "TL;DR" is 1) non-standard English/Internet slang 2) generational 3) might not be understood in all SE communities, and 4) has changed meanings over time anyway (Used to mean "Your response was too long, so I couldn't be bothered to read it." ... Now it's a stand in for "What *I* wrote is too long, so here's a 'Summary'").

Comment: I completely agree with the OP. Solution: simply replace "TL;DR" by "Summary".

Answer (score 11):

> This Code of Conduct helps us build a learning community

No, SE is not a learning community. It's a platform to share knowledge, but not specifically about *learning*. Several answers have already raised this point, but I wanted to mention it again because a fundamental misrepresentation in the very first sentence sets things off really badly.

> team, moderators¹, and anyone posting to Q&A sites or chat rooms

Remove the footnote. This sentence doesn't need that level of detail. Furthermore restricting moderators to diamond mods is wrong here: the sentence shouldn't be restricted to exclude editors, voters, and other curators, who would be called “moderators” on many Internet forums.

> Be kind. ​Be polite and friendly with others. Avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online

The recommendation to “avoid jokes” is good advice, but it doesn't fit under the heading “be kind”. Making jokes that are misinterpreted because the reader doesn't have the expected context is not unkindness.

> “I came to get help, not to get my question edited.”
>   → “Thanks for improving my question. I’m happy to provide any other info you’ll need to answer it.”

You've completely inverted the meaning between the “unfriendly” and the “friendly” formulations. That's sarcasm. Sarcasm in a text that recommends against sarcasm is a really bad idea.

> This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”

I really cannot bring myself to telling someone off for saying that posting one's homework assignment (“homework dump” post) is lazy. I'm pretty sure we have several “official-looking” meta posts across the network that use terms like “homework dump” and “lazy”, some of them mine, and I do not see any inappropriate conduct there. Asking strangers to do your homework for you *is* lazy.

> For most first-time misconducts, our moderators will (…) send you a warning

There are many cases where a warning is not sufficient for the first offence. I think this table as a whole is still too directive.

> This is how moderators generally handle reported issues: (*followed by a big image that draws attention because it's typeset differently*)

You're spending way too much reader attention on sanctions. The description of possible sanctions should be limited to one sentence. Make each word count!

> learning community.

Again, this is not a learning community.

Comment: Your statement "No, SE is not a learning community. It's a platform to share knowledge" confuses me. Sharing knowledge has value only when the knowledge being shared is new to the share-ee. Receiving new knowledge is, by definition, learning. Unless you're saying SE distributes only knowledge that everyone already has, I'm getting a contradiction. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @SOLO I saw this discussed in details in at least 4 prior answers that suggested to get rid of word "learning"

Comment: @gnat fair enough, I didn't read every previously written word before I commented here. (I _did_ read more thoroughly before posting my own answer a while ago. I remember seeing "learning" discussed, but it never rankled me enough to comment until the way it was presented in this answer specifically.) But c'mon, there are nearly 50 answers, some of which are tomes in and of themselves. With this much content, using a Q&A site for discussion kinda breaks down, and it's hard not to read new posts in isolation. Search has lots of false positives, not to mention that many hidden comments exist.

Answer (score 11):

Reading the very first bullet in the CoC ('If you're here for help') leaves with with an uncomfortable feeling that you are missing an opportunity to address a core cause of strife.

There are many different modes of asking for help. The SE sites are designed for a specific subset of those modes: *Posing concrete questions.* In my view, the external view of us as a bunch of heartless jerks comes from a disconnect here. People expect to open up a sort of support ticket and have an interaction with someone who will help them. There's nothing wrong with this idea -- except that it's not what these sites are designed to do. So even very polite deflections can be read as heartless. And, on the other hand, those who answer feel harassed to the point of snark by the flood of questions-that-are-not-concrete-questions.

So, I posit, the CoC might want to spent a phrase here setting the expectation, and distinguishing, briefly, 'I need help with X' from 'I did X, I got Y, I expected Z'.

Answer (score 10):

## If you can't say anything nice, don't say anything at all.

Explicitly recommend not commenting. People on the internet don't always seem to understand that that's a very good option. A good time to exercise this option is when the OP is wrong and you feel very strongly about that. Another time is when you fail to come up with a constructive response. Saying nice things instead of mean things it's great, but it's also harder, and it's not practical for a lot of people a lot of the time because constructive, kind human interaction is genuinely difficult, but it's much easier if we can actually choose the situations where we want to be kind and constructive. If I were enforcing a "be kind" clause in a code of conduct, I would feel on far better footing to point out to an offender that they didn't have to say anything at all, so the burden is not on the moderator or the platform to make sure it's always possible for them to say something nice.

I think the code of conduct is really incomplete without explicitly highlighting that not commenting is an active expectation we have alongside our active expectation for those who comment to comment constructively.

Comment: Many people have commented that the actual result here is to discourage human interaction. If so, I guess being clear about it would be good.

Comment: @Nemo rewrote a bit, but yes I would like to discourage human interaction when it's too damn difficult to interact kindly.

Answer (score 9):

I'd prefer formatting with [em dashes](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) in contrast to the double dashes used now.

From

> Be kind. Be polite and friendly with others. Avoid jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop engaging and move on.

To

> Be kind. Be polite and friendly with others. Avoid jokes and sarcasm — tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop engaging and move on.

Spaces around the em dash are considered optional.

Answer (score 9):

I have seen instances where codes of conduct have been used to "get rid of" members of a community for political reasons. What safeguards are in place to prevent this from happening at StackExchange?

Comment: Aren't the safeguards (listed in order of escalation)  Meta, the Moderator team, the Community Management team and the Contact Us page? I don't see how those currently in place and proven processes are going to be influenced by a CoC. This CoC only codifies how we, the community members, interact with each other in a respectful way. In its current form there is no sign it leans to a certain ideology nor do I see how it can be used directly to "get rid of"  members. The routes to handle (mod) abuse are unaffected so the safeguards that were already in place remain.

Comment: The difference now is that we have an official code of conduct, which can be selectively applied. IMO we've been doing just fine without one. Because we're all adults. Margaret Thatcher also thought it was no big deal when they introduced a "code of conduct" in parliament and look how it turned out.

Comment: *we're all adults* no, we're not. Age limit is 14 (16 if in the EU). I beg to differ we're doing fine, but can we agree on that we can do better? The CoC can't be selectively applied IMO. Anyone is bound to it. If selectivity is the case, raise an issue. I'm not sure why the Iron Lady has to be brought to the discussion but from a distance I would say the conservatives are to blame for heck of a lot of trouble, not just a failed CoC. One bad example doesn't make all other CoC's as bad.

Comment: @rene How would we know if it is selectively applied? Moderators pick and choose which posts/answers/comments to edit or delete, if they do not *have* to explain why they chose one and not another, then what prevents a moderator from being **silently** selective in their application of these rules and exercising personal animus or ideological bias?

Comment: @Amadeus depends a bit on the size of the site but on SO most stuff is flagged/edited and deleted by regular members. Mods are still only involved in stuff regular users can't solve on their own. Posts are still soft deleted so any non-mod with the right privileges can see what got deleted and by whom. And in fierce comment debates I assume those participate will notice if stuff gets deleted one-sided. I'm not saying it never happens, all I'm saying is that those issues are not new and having a CoC or a be nice policy doesn't change anything for what you seem to perceive as an issue.

Comment: Eyes, essentially. Lots and lots of eyes. All moderator actions are visible, and open to inspection from the communities that they serve, as well as us. There _have_ been instances where there were complaints that rules were being enforced selectively, and we expended precisely what was owed, which was hundreds of hours on our part investigating, talking, educating (the religious sites for context). We've yet to see the checks-and-balances break down, and massive reports of exclusion _is_ what prompted this.

Comment: This is probably worth asking as a separate question if my comment didn't give enough information; there's more background and depth we could go into.

Comment: @TimPost I am confused, what do you mean to say about lots of eyes and that mod actions are open to inspection from the communities, did you by chance mixed posts and comments? Deleted comments are visible only to moderators, this is neither lots of eyes (especially since moderators have lots of other things to do) nor anyhow possible to inspect by community

Comment: @TimPost As gnat says. Deleted text is only visible if readers bother to go see the edit, and even if they did there is no facility for us to vote on whether a moderator deletion was unfair and should be undone. (as there is if a regular *user* changes our post). Eyes don't help, there is no "nice" way to call attention to what seems a fundamentally unfair and selective deletion, with a vague CoC to cite that effectively rules out *nothing* for a moderator regardless of what the non-moderator community thinks. What's our recourse when moderators back each other and don't care what we think?

Answer (score 9):

## 'Moderators' is used problematically

Using 'moderator' without qualification, with the expectation that it excludes community moderation by ordinary members, decreases the visibility of the expectation of said moderation, and consequently both the availability of that information to new users and the likelihood that any user will engage in difficult community moderation when an opportunity is presented to them.  This in turn decreases site quality and increases elected moderator workload.

## Use '♦ Moderators' Instead

This covers community managers, elected mods, mods pro tempore for beta sites, and anyone else with ♦ - level privileges, which is probably what was intended.  This has the downside of being somewhat confusing on its own (i.e. it begs the question "What's a ♦ moderator?"), but the upside that it doesn't reinforce the incorrect idea that we have one set of secret moderators with no accountability as our bread and butter site management people, like many new users expect.

Comment: wording with "elected" would exclude [meta-tag:pro-tem-moderators], [meta-tag:community-managers], and also SE developers with diamond level access

Comment: I use "♦ mod[erator]" for this reason whenever it's relevant.

Comment: @gnat fair point.  I think the loss there is smaller, because the mistaken belief (all diamond mods are elected) is much less problematic, but it could be an issue I suppose.

Comment: I find that first sentence hard to follow. Could you break it up in a few sentences? Or add a few commas?

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I've made an attempt at clearing it up.

Answer (score 7):

*Thank you.*  This version is IMO a great improvement over the previous one, especially since I think it makes expectations very clear without allowing rules lawyers a lot of room to play.

I'm particularly pleased that it passes one of the most important (but rarely considered) tests for a set of rules: *Would we be happy if someone took the rules literally and enforced them as they were written?*  And I think the answer is now "Yes, we would be comfortable."

The one thing that struck me while reading it is primarily a style or wording issue, not one of substance.  The opening sentence says "This Code of Conduct helps us build a learning community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect."  "Kindness" seems just a bit...I don't know, touchy-feely? overly abstract? loaded?  I'm groping without success for just the right words. Regardless, I honestly think it will incline many readers of the CoC to hold the whole CoC in less respect than it it were left out.

It actually detracts from the point which is made much more robustly by the latter two items.  I think you'd have a stronger, clearer, cleaner statement if it just read "This Code of Conduct helps us build a learning community that is rooted in collaboration, and mutual respect."  Collaboration and mutual respect do not leave room for unkindness, anyway.

Regardless, thank you for listening to the feedback you got.

Comment: "without allowing rules lawyers a lot of room to play" you might want to read this answer and its comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312953/213575

Comment: "Yes, we would be comfortable." Who's "we"? That statement exemplifies the tragedy of this code. It sets a particular way of not making people uncomfortable above all else and ignores the fact that in doing so it makes people uncomfortable. I'm not part of the "we" you're speaking of. Incidentally, as I'm writing this, there's an answer right below yours (with the same number of upvotes) that starts with "I'm still not comfortable".

Comment: @joriki I understand your issues, and I once shared them.  But after 30 years of trying to define human relationships precisely -- why 30? Because I'm dense. I should have figured it out sooner! -- I concluded that we must *either* write a code of laws and create a judiciary and the whole apparatus of state *or* describe what we want so that reasonable people can improve their behavior and simply not accept rules lawyering from the the rest. Ultimately, we stand or fall based on the quality of the moderation and the sense of community we create or fail to create.

Answer (score 7):

## Holy [Carp](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/images/1/1a/Carp_escape.jpg), this is much better!

I see very little that I feel could be improved.

> Are you speaking English? If so, I can’t tell.
>
> ---
>
> “I think you’re asking how to add a swap after system installation. Is that correct?”

I think this alternative could be replaced with something more along the lines of "This is an English speaking site. While we'd like to help you, we first need to be able to understand your question."

This handles both questions posted in another language (and not on the not-English-version of the site, eg. Spanish SO) as well as questions posted in *poorly written English.* Sure, an attempt to understand ("I think you're asking X, is that right?") are nice, the key point that the "Are you speaking English?" comment is trying to make is: questions need to be readable, understandable, and posted in English.

> “I came to get help, not to get my question edited.”
>
> ---
>
> “Thanks for improving my question. I’m happy to provide any other info you’ll need to answer it.”

I would change "edited" to "closed" (e.g. "Why is my question being closed? I came here to get help!") as well as replacing the alternative to something like "no comment is needed (see Community Guidelines and How to Ask for more information)."

Comment: It's hard to know how to handle a poorly written question, other than editing the post to try and fix it.  Many non-native speakers realize that their second-language skills are lacking, but others might be offended. "This is an English speaking site..." "My question is in English!!! Why don't you understand it???"

Comment: True, but this is just a guide. It's not meant to delineate all possible comments. Just trying to find a *good selection.*

Comment: For the first case, I would propose something along the lines of: “I am sorry, but I find it very difficult to understand your English. I think you’re asking how to add a swap after system installation. Is that correct?”

Answer (score 7):

This looks significantly better then the first one. Most of what I feared would be invitations for people to rule lawyer over particularities has been removed, the language has been broadened and generalised such as to cover a wider area instead of narrow examples, and the importance of intent and good faith attempts to follow have been highlighted.

I'd suggest going a bit further with emphasizing intent instead of reaction in defining what is punishable, but this will serve well. I imagine for most people this will be a very uncontroversial and unconsequential change (as they're already not in the habit of routinely denigrating others for giggles), so if it does help anyone feel better about participating, that's a win in my book.

Answer (score 7):

The existing answers here look like they're mostly about the meaning and intent of the content, but you also asked for "small sentence tweaks" and "grammar fixes", so here we go with some copy editing:

### Document-wide

In the first "Our expectations" bullet point, you use a double dash. That should become a true em dash, and it should not be bordered by spaces. Same for other occurrences of the double dash. (Granted, the rule about spaces seems to be older usage, and now somewhat disputed; see [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9070), [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/), and [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) for more.)

For most of the document, you use the serial comma, but in the last bullet point on the first page, you do not. I'm not trying to start a holy war about whether the serial comma is appropriate, but I generally advocate for picking one style and sticking with it. In the case of this doc, it looks like one or two just got left out as typos.

The doc contains a blend of links in Markdown format and links that are underlined blue text. I suppose this is not necessarily an error, depending on your implementation process, but I figured better safe than sorry as far as mentioning it in this list, in case some formatting gets forgotten or not applied at all.

### Page 1

The footnote starts with "(?)". I can't tell whether this is an intentional use of some shorthand I'm unfamiliar with, or a typo.

### Page 2

Under "No bigotry", it might be clearer/less awkward to replace or supplement "and those are just a few examples" with a general description of what you're trying to cover, like "or other groups that people identify personally with".

### Page 3

In the left pane of the graphic, the text includes "send you a warning". This is the only time in the graphic where the word "you" is used. I recommend rephrasing that (example: "send the author a warning" or simply "send a warning") to remove "you"; it's good for pane-level parallelism, and the word could come off as a little accusatory, especially to the many readers will never deserve to be warned by a mod themselves.

In the right pane of the graphic, the context makes your meaning fairly clear, but the sentence is grammatically ambiguous. I'd change "displaying" to "who display" (or similar) to make it clear that the bad stuff is modifying "users" rather than "moderators".

There's a single dash on its own line in the middle of the page. I don't know if it's a placeholder for a horizontal rule or something, but it looks odd on its own.

"the respect our community members expects" should be "the respect our community members expect".

The header at the bottom of the page says "Stack Overflow"; earlier, you used the "$CommunityName$" shorthand. Should be changed to that shorthand if you mean SO the site, or changed to "Stack Exchange" if you mean the network. (You could argue for "Stack Overflow" meaning the network, but "Stack Exchange" as the network name is more consistent with the rest of the doc.)

Comment: Disagree on the page 2 suggestion, but the rest is good

Comment: Could you explain why you disagree? You think it's superfluous, or you're actively against that message, or you want more specifics, or...?

Comment: I think 'and those are just a few examples' makes it clear we expect users to understand what bigotry is, which we do.  I think your suggestion strays back into trying to nail hate speech down in a way that's unhelpful. 'I can't define it but I know it when I see it' is the right way to go here.

Comment: Okay. In that case we agree philosophically but disagree about the implementation details. When I read it, I thought the list of examples distracted from the message and made things unclear. Not much to do here other than shrug and say "communication is hard", I guess.

Answer (score 7):

First off, I appreciated having a PDF on Github. Google Docs and Github are both pretty sluggish on my computer, so being able to download and open it in my PDF reader was a lot nicer than the last time in Google Docs.

As for the document itself...

## The header

Mark Olson noticed a problem with the use of "kindness" in the header, but couldn't pin down the specific problem. I think that problem is that "kindness" is noticeably more casual than "collaboration" and "mutual respect". I'd suggest changing it to "courtesy" instead. I also think it would read better moving "can" to before "feel", and changing "We commit..." to "We are committed..." I've put the changes in italics below:

> This Code of Conduct helps us build a learning community that is rooted in *courtesy*, collaboration, and mutual respect​. Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a community where all people *can* feel welcome and participate, regardless of expertise or identity.
>
> *We are committed* to enforcing and improving the Code of Conduct. It applies to everyone using $CommunityName$ and the Stack Exchange network, including our team, moderators 1, and anyone posting to Q&A sites or chat rooms.

## Our Expectations

I agree with Rob that researching your question is something the community generally expects, and I feel that it would fit well under the first bullet. The part about feedback is a bit redundant and would be better placed under the feedback bullet. I'm not sure the volunteers sentence is actually important.

> If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you​. *Include your research and what you've already tried when asking a question so we can provide the best answer.*

I'm pretty sure new people are the only ones who will need to learn about our community, so "especially if someone is new" is probably redundant in the next bullet. I've read a lot about people having a hard time with the StackExchange model, treating it like a forum instead, so maybe that was what you intended? It seems like a good thing to mention here.

> If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming​. Learning how to participate in our community can be daunting, especially *for people who are used to discussion forums instead*. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.

To put some comments by Tom Limoncelli and Tim into an answer, I'd suggest the following rewording for the next bullet:

> *Give and expect feedback. Kind, respectful, clear and constructive feedback is an essential part of our culture. When someone suggests an improvement, consider how you can use it to improve your question or answer.*

Like others, I agree with avoiding humor all together being trouble, but the warning still sounds reasonable to me. I think "friendly" and "kindly" are a bit inconsistent with the otherwise professional-sounding writing, and it took me a minute to figure out what "engaging" meant in this context. My suggested rewrite:

> Be kind.​ Be polite and *respectful to* others. *Be careful with* jokes and sarcasm -- tone is hard to decipher online *and it can be easy to misinterpret*. If a situation makes it hard to act *respectfully, leave the situation* and move on.

## Unacceptable behavior

The second bullet might benefit from some examples like the first. An example of an example:

> - Personal attack: People who believe in rocks are lazy, ignorant idiots who can't be bothered to do a simple google search and read about the mountains of evidence proving they don't exist.
> - Personal-feeling attack: This question is lazy and ignorant. It doesn't account for the mountains of articles a simple google search pulls up for "do rocks exist". Spoiler alert: They don't.
> - Subtly personal attack: A google search for "do rocks exist" would turn up mountains of articles proving they actually don't.
> - Focusing on the content: I noticed your question is important whether or not rocks exist. If you remove the paragraph about rocks, it would be easier to read and likely see more people who can answer.

On the "No bigotry" bullet, I'd prefer to just say "groups they identify with" and leave it at that rather than making a list of them.

"When in doubt, just don't" is witty and concise. It also feels flippant to me and reads like a subtle put-down. Maybe it's just the negativity in this section getting to me, but I dislike it a lot. I'd go for this instead:

> No bigotry.​ We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on the groups they identify with. When in doubt, it never hurts to rephrase it more tactfully or omit the remark entirely.

## Reporting and Enforcement

Personally, I don't care whether flagging alerts moderators or triggers an automatic deletion. The process could involve chanting while interrogating a rubber duck taped to a counterfeit Mona Lisa and I'd be perfectly fine with that (well, maybe it'd be a bit creepy). What matters to me is whether the bad stuff goes away.

Saying "We'll respond as quickly as we can" on the Contact part but not the Flag part suggests contacting you gets faster results than flagging the content. I suspect you'd prefer the opposite implication so the moderators can handle the stuff they can and leave staff more time to handle what moderators can't.

"We take your reports seriously" is topically similar to the bullets and dissimilar to the remainder of the paragraph. Combined with the colon at the end of the first paragraph, it makes more sense to me interpreting the bullets and two surrounding paragraphs as a broader "reporting and enforcement" paragraph, briefly interrupted by a bulleted list, rather than a narrower "What you can do" paragraph (with bulleted list) followed by a "what will happen" one.

Thanks to the above interpretation, "We take your reports seriously" is most closely associated with the Contact bullet. By combining with the "We'll respond as quickly as we can" problem, it implies you take contacting more seriously than flagging. Again, that would promote contacting first and flagging second.

It also occurred to me while writing this that I was operating under the assumption that flagging and contacting were equivalent. A brief look at the contact form suggests they're actually very different, and should probably be addressed separately.

I'd rearrange things as follows:

> Every person contributes to creating a kind, respectful community. If you find unacceptable behavior directed at yourself or others, you can *flag the content to alert the moderators. We take flags seriously and will respond as quickly as we can.*
>
> Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct​ in good faith​ may 
>   face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team. *All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators.* This is how moderators generally handle reported issues:
>
> {graphic}
>
> If you have concerns about how a moderator has handled a situation, you can contact us directly.

I'd personally like to see the middle section of the graphic softened a little. It suggests to me that making one (different) mistake per month for six months would get me suspended, even if I'm clearly trying to improve. I'm pretty sure the moderators would avail themselves of the "case-by-case basis" part to just give a warning in each case, which makes the middle section seem overly harsh to me. Or maybe my lack of experience with moderators has driven a false assumption and they really *would* suspend me for that, in which case I suppose that's fine to leave in.

Also, the hard-of-seeing will need some OCR tools to read that graphic if you don't include an alt text or replace it with plain text.

## The footer

The term "avenues" seems to be synonymous with "methods" in this context, but I don't think that's what you intended. I suggest changing it to "direction" instead.

> We created this Code of Conduct because it reinforces the respect our community members expect from one another. Also, having a code provides us with *a clear direction* to correct our culture should it stray off-course.

## Chat TL;DR

I don't have much (any) experience with Chat, but I get the impression it's more of a "learning and social" community than just a "learning" one.

## Emotional summary

I feel apathetic toward the TL;DR sections, largely because they're essentially duplicates of what I've already read. I'd likely feel differently if I hadn't already read everything else and made them redundant, or if they had been at the top instead. It's probably not typical that someone would read the whole document and *then* the TL;DR though, so I think it's all right.

I feel fairly neutral about the Reporting and Enforcement section. It feels like impassively describing the system to me. I think that's okay too.

I feel a little depressed reading the Unacceptable Behavior section. There's a lot of negativity. I think I feel like it's accusing me of being the type of person who *would* do those kinds of things. I don't like the section. I understand it's necessary, but I still don't like reading it.

I like the Our Expectations section best. I know I hit on it pretty hard, but it's still my favorite and I think that's why I did. It has a lot of potential to be friendly, positive and welcoming. It also feels like good advice for life in general, not just StackExchange. If I were the kind of person who put motivational stuff on my wall, I'd make the edits I suggested and pin the first section up.

I might do that anyway.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so I might read things differently. I like both your analysis and how your suggestions improve shortcomings. I have one remark:There are more answers (*likely* versus *intent*) that suggest improvements on the  *No bigotry* part. While *Just don't* might be witty, doesn't it have a different *feel* to it then to say *rephrase to something more kind.*? Doesn't that latter phrasing leave a loophole to alienate groups in a kind way?

Comment: @rene: I intended there to be a change in how the reader feels after reading it. Right now it's witty, but also flippant, which risks making the reader feel belittled. I wanted to make it more respectful to prevent those feelings, and hopefully invoke more positive ones instead. If I invoked a negative feeling instead, that was unintentional and I'd like to know. Looking back at it now, I feel like it could actually still use some improvement, so I'm glad you drew my attention to it. I'll give it some more thought and try to improve it some more.

Comment: I assumed that kindly alienating people would be difficult, if not impossible, so there may be a loophole in the wording I chose. Personally, I think having a hard-to-exploit loophole is the lesser of the two evils (compared to a flippant code of conduct), but avoiding both evils would certainly be even better. If you can suggest any improvements, I'll try to incorporate them into my answer. If not, I still appreciate your taking the time to help me improve. =)

Comment: I have to read this whole CoC with a dictionary close by, so don't count on me suggesting *improvements*. If you want to make it worse, I'm all in ...

Comment: @rene: I feel like my rephrasing of the bigotry section still had hints of flippancy in it, so I rephrased it again to suggest increasing tact or omitting the remark entirely. Rules laywers could still argue that they shouldn't be punished because they weren't in doubt, but I think the intended audience is people who don't know any better, rather than people trying to get out of trouble, so the loophole is probably okay unless we can figure out another better way to phrase it.

Comment: Also, if you added the sentence "I think it would be worth trying to improve that if possible" to the end of your first comment, you'd have a polite, specific, and personal attack free, suggestion for improving my answer. It was basically a suggestion for improvement already. And it inspired me to go back and revise that section to be a little better. I think you can definitely suggest improvements.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting and I definitely find  this version better then the first one. I'm glad this worked out this way. Pleasant experience, learned a bit and became a tad wiser in the process.

Answer (score 7):

> “This is called Invariance and Covariance. […]”

Do not capitalise *invariance* and *covariance.* If you want to highlight that this about the word itself, use italics or quotes.

Answer (score 7):

> - **No bigotry.** We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion -- and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.

It’s clear that this bullet prohibits throwing insults because of who someone is or what they believe (at least, within the four listed categorizations). Attacking someone with a comment like “you’re an up-tight, narrow-minded religious bigot” is not allowed.

However, this bullet is ambiguous as to whether it *also* prohibits questions and answers that **touch on topics or contain information that might offend others**. For example, it’s possible that the premise of a question or a fact proposed in an answer might imply that there is a God (which could offend atheists) or that there is no God (which could offend theists). At least up until now, questions and answers along these lines have been allowed on relevant SO sites as part of discussing allowed topics.

In light of this bullet’s text, it’s not clear if they’ll still be allowed. Would you consider clarifying to remove this ambiguity?

If this bullet is intended to prohibit content that might offend, then it seems that should be made crystal clear. If the intent is to prohibit personally-directed attacks that incorporate who someone is or what they believe in their unkindness, it seems this is already covered by the previous point (“No name-calling or personal attacks.”)—if needed, the explanation given with that bullet could be expanded to explicitly address attacks based on who someone is or what they believe. If the intent is something else, hopefully this point’s wording can be clarified in a way that states that intent without ambiguity.

Answer (score 6):

#### How do we know what language is acceptable, now?

I have a problem right now, with an answer on IPS in which I used the word "damn" for emphasis; specifically somebody lifting a dog by "his damn ear." It has received over two hundred upvotes; but moderators insist on deleting "damn" as profanity.

As an excuse, many point at [This Answer by Jeff Atwood,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22233/395268) (SE Developer and User #1), in which he says:

> ...  in general you should not use expletives anywhere, under any circumstances. If you can't effectively communicate what you need to say without resorting to lowest common denominator cursing, then keep it to yourself.

However, he leaves the question of "what exactly is an expletive?" unanswered. By the dictionary the British word "bloody" is an expletive, so is "wicked". Are these banned?

Consider [this 2009 answer **By Jeff Atwood**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12707/395268):

> Hey man, I had to do all the work to format that damn thing into 140 characters!
>   Where's my credit for that?!?

I infer from that Jeff did not consider "damn" as an intensifier to fall into the realm of "lowest common denominator cursing". Nor should it be so considered, it is considered "mild language" and isn't even bleeped on prime time broadcast TV. It is in the Title of books; "How to Write a Damn Good Novel," (Mystery / Thriller). It is used without issue in *thousands* of SE questions and answers, and over 40 times on IPS alone.

The issue I am having with moderators now is just an example; a selectively enforced vague warning gives liberty to those in power to exercise their own bigotries and whims that are shared by very few others.

Yes, the police force needs the power to enforce the law, but that law should not be so vague that the police just shut up whomever they want for whatever reason they want and can always say "the law says it is my judgement call," while leaving hundreds and thousands of others, doing exactly the same thing, unmolested.

I'd like **more** clarification on what kind of language is acceptable on SE. Our users are specifically NOT supposed to be children, I don't think G-rated language is the answer. Certainly, any language, profane or not, used to insult another user should be prohibited, insults *should* be deleted. My issue is with "mild language", PG-13 language, that is not even bleeped on American prime time major network shows. If our users could hear it there, I see no reason to flag it on SE.

The language "likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion" is far too vague.

**I am an atheist.** Just saying that offends some deeply religious people, not to mention detailing anything about how an atheist approaches life or morals. Other deeply religious people are offended by any discussion of sex, homosexuality, promiscuity, rape ... All of which are relevant topics in Writing for novels or screenplays. If somebody strongly disagrees with me, have I offended or alienated them? If a *moderator* strongly disagrees with me, can they with impunity censor me for offending their personal taste in language?

Comment: Even "mild" language is not necessary, and it is not professional either. It also may offend sensitive users, so whether Jeff or a 1 rep user uses any 'questionable' language, it should be removed.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ Except it isn't, as I said, there are literally thousands of answers including the word "damn." Making this *extremely* selectively enforced.

Comment: I definitely would note cite some of Jeff's writing as acceptable language. He hasn't been with SO for the better part of a decade, and we *definitely* don't put up with that sort of language.

Comment: As to being an Atheist - in whichever context, are you saying that as a statement of fact or with the intent of being controversial? Going to one of our religious sites and proselytizing for Atheist (or any other) views isn't going to fly. Mentioning your beliefs (or lack thereof) in a general discussion (say in chat) should be fine. Context matters.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that your initial edit specifically said "god damn", it was removed by two different moderators three times as unnecessary and offensive until you tried with *only* "damn" (after rolling it back yet again to "god damn") and then specifically pinged me to let me know that you'd made the change. At that point, I was tired of the edit warring, rolled back and locked the post to prevent it from continuing. As a note, I'm also an Atheist, so the edit has nothing to do with offending my personal beliefs.

Comment: @Catija I made that change from "god damn" to "damn" immediately after the rollback, specifically to make it less offensive. If you are fine with only "damn" then I'll leave it that way; otherwise if you think it offensive either way, why mention the difference? Your note says it will be discussed on meta, but now you say you just don't want to allow any discussion *at all.* I mentioned "atheism" as another example of my belief I have been targeted elsewhere by a moderator for discussing atheism in a context where religion was specifically the nature of the OP question (on writing fiction).

Comment: @HDE226868 My point is; moderators are fond of pointing at Jeff Atwood's response to "expletives" or quoting it to justify their idea that "damn" is "not nice," while the other link shows he used it himself (reportedly along with "crap"): Clearly indicating his definition of "expletive" did *not* include mild language a majority of adults use in common conversation. As for answers with "damn":  44 on IPS, 54 on Academia, 132 on Writing, and 3853 on Stack Overflow. Clearly this prohibition is **selectively** enforced. A recipe for moderators exercising prejudice, like cops & traffic law.

Comment: @Amadeus None of this has any relevance to the Code of Conduct, because the use of the word wasn't okay before the CoC and isn't going to be okay after it's implemented. If the word exists in posts, it's more likely just because it hasn't been seen. Moderators can't see every post; we just can't.

Comment: @HDE226868 On the contrary, it is an **example** of what is wrong with the CoC, it is too vague to prevent moderators from exercising power out of personal irritation or animus. As the new CoC is written, almost anything a moderator doesn't like can be censored on the grounds it might make someone, somewhere, someday, uncomfortable. There is nothing in that ensures consistency or due process or allows any sort of appeal or vote on it. My situation is an example of this arbitrary and inconsistent enforcement **actually happening.**

Comment: @Amadeus: As an example of "arbitrary and inconsistent enforcement", your example is pretty... trivial. Nothing meaningful was changed by removing that word. You have not been prevented from communicating the information you wanted to communicate. As such, I don't see any genuine *problems* from this "arbitrary and inconsistent enforcement". If you think removing the word "damn" is censoring, then you are seriously misusing the term.

Comment: @NicolBolas It is my post, and I think it has diminished emotional impact without the emphasis. Obviously removing the word "damn" is censorship, otherwise what is the point of moderating? Censorship is a good thing, there are offensive expletives that *should* be censored. If you think "damn" is one of those expletives, then you are seriously misusing the term. If you don't think "damn" is one of them, then its removal is arbitrary and inconsistent because *then* it's removal was not done for any valid "be nice" reason at all!

Comment: 1.A simple dictionary check shows that it is a curse word: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/damn . ; 2.Imho we are going for the most objective, least emotional answers. That's what is professional courtesy.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile You misread read that. It says as a verb, a *synonym* for "damn" is "curse". I did not use it as a verb, I used it as an adjective for emphasis (his damn ear), in the same sense as "damned": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/damned which has no synonym "curse" or "swear". Now that this is cleared up, by your Merriam-Webster criterion, if I change it to "damned" I am fine? IMHO, speaking as both a college professor and a professional paid writer, I am going for the most memorable lessons; and in this particular answer about cruelty to a dog, emotionalism was warranted.

Comment: If it: (1) is questionable and (2) creates a disruption then you probably need to consider changing it. Also, Jeff has _not_ worked here for quite a while now, which doesn't make him an ideal source of current policy :) He was also, sometimes famously, not particularly adept at following his own advice, just like the rest of us.

Comment: I just updated the answer to that question that Jeff originally wrote. If you try to take a little liberty and use certain milder words for style and emphasis and someone objects to it (especially a moderator, who is likely reacting to flags from other users) - take it out.

Comment: @TimPost I received over 100 upvotes on that answer without a single flag, and the moderator changed it. So what if the moderator is NOT reacting to flags by other users, but out of what may be personal animus or bias against what *at least* 100 others did *not* find objectionable? (No telling how many read it, without flagging it, in order to get 100+ upvotes). Clearly even on IPS moderators don't care about the 44 other 'damns', your unilateral change of Jeff's post to make a new policy doesn't fix selective, biased enforcement. I never saw a flag on my answer and was never notified of one.

Answer (score 5):

> Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct ​in good faith​ may
>   face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team.

I fail to make sense of the function of *in good faith* in this sentence and I honestly do not understand what you want to communicate here.

I see the following groupings of the parts in this sentence:

- > Those who don’t (follow the Code of Conduct ​in good faith​)

  Here the only difference made by *in good faith* is to add users who follow the CoC in bad faith (to those who don’t follow the CoC). I could understand this as a catch-all clause for those who adhere to the CoC but are disruptive anyway. If you really want to communicate this, this should be less subtle. However, I doubt that this is what you want to say since it would implicitly the CoC to be incomplete.
- > Those who don’t (follow the Code of Conduct) ​in good faith​

  Here the effect of *in good faith* is that it explicitly excludes those who break the CoC in bad faith – which would be absurd.

My best guess is that you want to say something like:

> Those who violate the Code of Conduct (even in good faith) may face repercussions […]

Comment: I'd hope the "in good faith" means the opposite of what you guessed, because it would be pointless to even have that bunch of words in there if "in good faith" wouldn't be to the users advantage.

Comment: Would it even be possible to have a CoC that is complete? There'll always be people who look for loopholes to exploit.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Well, you can have a catch-all clause (e.g., “thou shalt not harm the community”). But then it should be more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikiquettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Etiquette), ([permalink](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia:Etiquette&oldid=847531355)) the code-of-conduct in Wikipedia; seem to be more brief, to-the-point and clear than our's. Although they *have lot of similarity with ours'* ; they have a big dissimilarity in the range of flexibility.

They did not made any religious script of "this type of wording is bad". They simply left it over on readers' discretion.

Here are quote from wikipedia:

> - **Assume good faith.** Wikipedia has worked remarkably well so far based on a policy of nearly complete freedom to edit. People come here to collaborate and write good articles.
> - ***Keep in mind that raw text may be ambiguous*** and often seems ruder than the same words coming from a person standing in front of you. Irony is not always obvious when written. Remember that text comes without facial expressions, vocal inflection, or body language. Be careful choosing the words you write: what you mean might not be what others understand. Likewise, be careful how you interpret what you read: what you understand might not be what others mean.
> - **Do not intentionally make misrepresentations. Apologise if you inadvertently do so.**
> - **Do not ignore** reasonable questions.
> - Although it is understandably difficult in an intense argument, *if **other editors are not as civil as you** would like them to be, **be more civil, not less***. That way at least you are not moving towards open conflict and name-calling; *by your own action you are actively doing something about it.* Try to treat others with dignity—they are people as well.
> - Be prepared to apologize. In animated discussions, we often say things we later wish we had not. Say so.
> - Forgive and forget.
> - Recognize your own [**biases**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_bias), and keep them in check.
> - Give praise when it's due. Everybody likes to feel appreciated, especially in an environment that often requires compromise. Drop a friendly note on users' talk pages.

This makes a whole lot of difference, with amazing flexibility. From the quoted text I have highlighted the most important portions.

On the current examples, I felt, pointing at "This type of language is bad language" could have bad consequences, particularly the current "unacceptable" or "unfriendly" column **does not contains any direct hate speech** like "You should die" or "Get lost from here".

They are some **absolutely normal sentences** (to my view) which have scope of ambiguous emotional interpretation (for some other people). So I think the column for example of "unwanted language" is inappropriate. This sort of ambiguity is unavoidable time to time, from most decent people. So these can't be a criterion for a confirmed "unfriendly" or "unacceptable".

Although that column hurted and confused me a lot. I'm not telling to  completely  go without examples (as wikipedia did; they completely avoided examples); *because to explaining what to avoid, but without citing examples, could have some other consequences*.

So instead telling those examples "unacceptable" or "unfriendly"; they  should be renamed as **"could be confusing or misunderstood as unfriendly"**, and they should keep scope of apologising (as wikiquette tells "Do not intentionally make misrepresentations. Apologise if you inadvertently do so.") and clearing up any misunderstanding. **otherwise this column is going to punish a lot of innocent people**.

Thanks.

Comment: I found your last paragraph a bit difficult to follow. Maybe its first sentence should be "I also think that examples are unavoidable to explain something." Then the next part ("But the current...") would start a new sentence. I think that would make the post more clear.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know I am trying to improve language and meaning.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I have done the edits

Comment: Good work! I, for one, find it clearer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here.

I think the "Google it" culture might need some tweaking. Here are my two reasons:

- Many visitors to Stack Exchange are here exactly because they are in the process of Googling the question they are trying to answer. It is quite frustrating to Google for an answer to a question and the number one result is a Stack Exchange article telling you to search Google for an answer to your question. This problem grows with the popularity of Stack Exchange.
- "Google it" is not a repeatable, time-invariant, location-invariant solution. Depending on how long ago the original answer was posted, Google may return vastly different results. Depending on where you live Google may return vastly different results. Depending on your browser cookies, you may get vastly different (and potentially less useful) results to the Stack Exchange member answering this question.

I would prefer the following:

> I Googled "Invariance Covariance" and the first result was [insert link]. See if that link helps. Try performing a similar search to see if it gives you a better explanation than what we can in a comment here.

Answer (score 3):

My main concern with this site in past years was that it gamified moderation.  This caused a lot of problems, because it became an easter egg hunt to find reasons to criticize the questions and answers of those here simply to enlighten and be enlightened.  If these changes helped reduce *that* problem, I'll be very greatful.

Comment: I would be very surprised to see *any* evidence of *any* feature on the sites that specifically rewards any sort of negative moderation action. I don't believe any such thing exists, or has ever existed. SE does gamify moderation, but always through e.g. badges that don't care whether suggested edits are approved or rejected, questions left open or closed, etc — just review items completed.

Answer (score 3):

> Avoid **jokes** and sarcasm.

From what point in time does this new Code of Conduct apply? Specifically, does it apply retrospectively to "historical" jokes such as these:

- [Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/252576)
- [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184618/252576)
- [Stack Overflow needs direct-to-brain interface for post-human users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21053/202356)

Is the "historical" value of these jokes greater than the value of the Code of Conduct? In other words, can these "historical" jokes be deleted now, and the undeserved reputation earned from these jokes be withdrawn?

Comment: That last example does not read as a joke to me. Does that make this answer a joke? On a more serious note: I assumed most of the concerns are about comments. And while the *avoid jokes* could certainly apply to answers to some extent, I think it would be pretty unwelcoming if a fresh question gets called out for being a joke.

Comment: @rene The question may not be a joke, but it has been locked? Nonetheless, that is not really my point. My point is does the new CoC apply to existing jokes, which they have themselves kept around for "historical" reasons?

Comment: If anything, they apply to existing exchanges between users, yes. But in that case you need to link to comments, not posts because I honestly don't see how posts by itself (if not rude/low quality) will be subject as a whole to the CoC. Parts of it, maybe. Edit old posts, sure but if your use of the word *delete* refers to a whole Q/A I feel we're overreaching the goal. I don't think the CoC is primarily about the content itself. It is about those that provide the content and those that share their opinion about that content.

Comment: If a post is a bad joke, saying so in a comment should not be met with hostility. If a post with a bad joke is on-topic and can stay on the site/should be moderated is still governed on the per-meta-site. The exchanges in the conversation are more governed by the CoC then actual content (but that doesn't mean that in posts we now allow to be rude / joking / sarcastic) but I don't think that was a huge problem (maybe on sites like IPS or the religion sites this is different)

Comment: @rene I have now removed the 4th example. Can we now focus on the actual question? To reiterate, are "historical" jokes allowed by the CoC?

Comment: The CoC is not meant to govern content. That is where the per-meta sites is for. So, if historical jokes in post content were allowed, they still are under the new CoC.

Comment: Ok, so jokes and sarcasm are not allowed in the comments, but they are allowed in the posts? That's a pretty interesting interpretation of CoC.

Comment: I don't really think punishment ought to be retroactive. However if a question no longer meets the standards of the site - in terms of tone or content, voting to close appropriately seems like the right thing to do. As for the rep, meh, I don't really think it should be special cased and ought to be treated like any other deleted post. The NARQiness is the real issue here

Comment: I'm known for my pretty interesting interpretations ... I'm also often wrong.

Comment: @rene Well, thankfully, at least witty comments have not been disallowed. :-)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yeah, that sounded like the right thing to do to me as well, but instead they decided to keep those jokes around because of "historical" values. I don't really get it, but I guess it is something akin to Wikipedia's Bad Jokes and Other Deleted Nonsense, except for the "deleted" part. I find it very confusing when people define new rules/laws/guidelines/code, etc. and then say that it doesn't apply in these specific reasons because of some Noodle Incident.

Answer (score 2):

The following comments showed up on a new user's post. Names removed.

> Apology not accepted. Fix it. There is no excuse. No, I'm not going to tilt my head upside down. Closing as unclear, and -1 for not just fixing the problem. – One User

The next has a quote by op apologizing to reply to:

> (Sorry for the wrong image orientation) You should also apologize for asking a question that is unanswerable. It's like me asking you if you like my Aunt's cooking. You know nothing about my Aunt same as we know basically nothing about this alternator. How do you expect anyone to be able to give a decent answer? -2nd User
>
> "The type id on the plate would make it unambiguously answerable." This is an ironic (and somewhat of a hypocritical) statement. Then why ask us in the first place? Also, it is hard to interpret the this identification because I can't tell if that's a B or an 8, or if that says 65 at the end, etc. Admittedly, to expect us to clearly see every little detail on this picture and to not tell us any numbers that you see on this seems rather unreasonable and arrogant. -3rd User

They were flagged as unkind, which a moderator quickly declined. Are these not the type of things the new conduct code are supposed to target?

If not, shouldn't they be? And shouldn't moderators agree to adhere to this? Because it seems that the code of conduct proposed is simply a sign on the wall that no one reads, especially the ones that are supposed to enforce it.

**Point being that either the CoC is not being communicated properly in its examples, or its not being communicated properly to moderation teams. The *next* revision needs to take that into account.** I am not looking for a reply or answer, these are rhetorical questions to illustrate an issue with the CoC as implemented.

Comment: This question doesn't seem like the right place for this discussion.

Comment: I don't like to the question or site because this isn't so much about that specific question, as general reply to what the CoC is supposed to cover. @Chair If you can help anonymize it or change it that would be great.

Comment: @Chair is that edit better?

Comment: I think it's _okay_ here, but if you'd like responses your answer might be better as a question in it's own right.

Comment: Not looking for a reply or answer, these are rhetorical questions to illustrate an issue with the CoC as implemented.

Comment: That 2nd and 3th comment that you cite, explain to the asker what is wrong with their question. Removing them, IMO, would be throwing out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: This isn't going to happen overnight. We've got a lot of communication that we need to have with (now, 600+ !!) moderators to help them identify varying types of caustic comments, and provide some guidance on what to do (moderators on our network have quite a bit of autonomy, and that's not something we want to change). This is also the _first_ release version of the CoC, we _may_ need to change some language to be more specific (I don't think we will, mostly noting that we're not closed to the idea). [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] And even when we achieve a new level of consistency, there will _always_ be crashes, and you'll _always_ hear about those yet seldom about the million other questions that went perfectly fine. We have an obligation to pay attention to and learn from every single incident, but one big belly-flop doesn't negate significant forward progress, which I feel we're making :)

Comment: @slbarth that can be conveyed a different way, and allowing comments that are rude as long as they have some percentage of helpful goes against what this CoC is supposed to do. Nothing stopping those commenters from saying the same thing but nicer or At least not insultingly. The code has an example of calling the a post lazy. Is arrogant and hypocritical not the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

- On "no subtle put-downs", you're inviting moderators to overreach. Subtle things are hard to judge, and banning them tells moderators it is ok to dive into things reasonable people might disagree on. It'd be better to go the opposite way and refuse to act on subtle things. And the examples are things that probably should not be banned; sometimes in societies people get frustrated with each other. Expressing that should be okay. You're building this for humans.
- On the other hand, the "no name-calling or personal attacks" seems workable and positive.
- On "no bigotry", there's really no way to do this right. "Likely to offend" is not the right standard - people get offended about all sorts of things, and trying to control people's language will (rightly) offend them too.
- On "No harassment", you should probably prefer a less expansive definition of harassment, focused on repeated unwanted contact after requests to stop. Other offenses should be discussed as separate things.
- Also, banning jokes seems culture-killing, and I think would require exceptionally strong justification.

Answer (score 0):

"Thanks for improving my question..."

This could not be more condescending. That should be something along the lines of, "Can you explain why you edited my question so I can leave high quality content here in the future", not "Thank you for feeding me your scraps high rep overlords"

Other than that I thought it was good.

Comment: The downvote(s) are going to be along the rational of "your interpretation is wrong." And that has to do with the fact that it is...and *exactly why the previous CoC document was bad.* So, thanks!

Comment: @Draco18s I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying. Could you rephrase your explanation?

Comment: My explanation is that the previous draft Code of Conduct was poor because it is possible for two people to interpret the same phrase in different ways. Your post here takes a phrase and misinterprets it *really* badly ("bad" in this context meaning "not friendly"). The misinterpretation is likely the reason for any downvotes (the answer was at -1 when I made my comment).

Comment: It's still possible for that.

Comment: Yes, it is, but it's *better* than it was before. Speaking on this example line in particular, [I took objection to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312890/313685) in a different way.

Comment: @Draco18s I think you're confusing improvement for meeting standards. It's better, but it's not where it needs to be. Stack Overflow has a real problem with high reputation users running rough-shot on low rep users. This isn't going to help that problem, and that's basically the cause of Stack Overflow being so unwelcoming. This is another place that SO is not capitalizing on achieving their goals with this entire campaign.

Comment: I agree that this example is poor, but I think it's because instead of the "unfriendly" and "friendly" options presenting alternative wording for the same idea, the two are intended to be fundamentally different responses.  And that's not wrong in itself, either, but it doesn't fit with the other examples presented.

Answer (score -3):

Others have [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313207/180367) regarding downvotes, but here is my suggestion.

> Consider giving explanations when downvoting questions and/or answers. Knowing the problem with their contribution will help them rectify the problem and/or make better contributions in the future.

Of course this does not necessitate commenting, but leaves it to the discretion of the possible downvoter.

Answer (score -4):

I agree with majority of answers: great improvements, thanks for listening to our feedback!

The only small thing I'm missing now is to speak about voting. When it's about welcoming atmosphere of the site, downvoting new users' questions may hurt a lot.

I think about something along the lines of

> be patient with new users, suggest improvements and ask for clarification instead of down-voting.

(honest questions doesn't deserve downvoting, blatantly off-topic / spam questions will be closed / deleted anyway).

---

### To address down votes and the comment about requirement for new users:

I fully agree that posts of new users should have the same requirements as established users' posts.

And I think way of keeping those standards are closure and deletion of questions.

Voting is not a way of moderation, it's the way to express opinion

- up-vote means agreement with the post,  appreciation of the effort / knowledge demonstrated...
- down-vote means disagreement, expressing frustration overt a low quality post...

What I try to explain is that down vote on new users' questions had more negative effect than educating.

Changing CoC have started by realising SE network isn't very welcoming, not welcoming new users with a down vote would be a good start to improve.

Comment: I agree with you here. While the intent of the downvote function is solid, young people, new to SE, often take the downvote a little personally - I certainly used to. Of course, they shouldn't take it personally, but they're young and still of that mindset. In every day life, one would think about how they are communicating criticism to a young person, specifically because of their tendency to take it personally.

Comment: I've seen a number of people on other platforms (Quora, for one) complain of a hostile culture here. While an experienced member may look at a vague newbie question with hardly any details and downvote and laugh behind their keyboard at it's absurdity, while leaving a cold, assertive comment - I think it's worth thinking about how the asker might feel about that. I mean, the rules already mandate the omission of words with negative connotations in the aims of not offending others, surely not responding harshly to new users is in the same spirit?

Comment: I agree that downvoting can be demoralising to new users, and many users in general! But that's more or a sensitivity issue I guess, how sensitive should one be to being downvoted. If the downvote is accompanied by rudeness or belittling then that's an issue, downvoting itself... maybe one has to understand why/how it operates.

Comment: @SaltySub I don't have issues with downvoting in general, just downvoting on questions of new users. They come to here asking for help, and the first thing they meet is something negative. "But that's more or a sensitivity issue I guess" - I've to disagree here, if we start considering users "over sensitive" then we just go back to where we've started before the new CoC

Comment: Being downvoted hurts. Especially if you don't understand why the downvote is deserved.

Comment: I could not agree more and am very surprised that this is downvoted so much. Addressing this very issue is one of the best ways to keep this site relevant for new users. Alienating new users will eventually result in this forum becoming obsolete. I wish people saw this very obvious conclusion.

Comment: @Andrew: I agree! Hope mods will read this answer too and take into account despite the balance of votes.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Yeah on that point it's kind of a UX thing really... Say I'm new, I come to a site asking a question, and I get downvoted straight away. Then I'd be like, what? Why did I even come here in the first place? New users would be taken aback and reallly from a UX perspective it doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: New users are subject to the exact same standards as established ones.  They don't get a pass because they're new.  Doing so really makes a dichotomy between the shift from new user to established.  You vote on content.  It doesn't matter whether a 100k user or a 1 rep user posts it.  If it's bad, it's bad.  Period.

Comment: @fbueckert please see my update

Comment: Voting has literally nothing to do with being welcoming.  It's about content curation.  You're still advocating for not being critical of new user's posts, which is something any long term curator is going to disagree with.

Comment: @fbueckert so here we disagree.

Comment: There is no a priori reason why people should react to downvoting more strongly than to upvoting. The solution is to find out what in the world out there makes people think a downvote is a big deal. Are users trained that way by YouTube or some other website? (Remember when YouTube used to have 5 stars but only 2 of them were really used?)

Comment: @Nemo: you're exactly right, down-vote shouldn't be a big deal, however users feel it is, and this isn't something we can change, especially not for new users.

Answer (score -4):

> No bigotry. We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion -- and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.

Totally approve of this message. I'd like to see another item on that list though:

- Lack (or amount) of knowledge

The worst offenses I've seen on this site comes from people who feel that questions asked are beneath them, and yet take the time to complain about the intelligence of the poster and then explain why they won't answer the question.

I understand that this behavior falls directly under the "Be Nice" rule. Explicitly stating that treating people poorly - who have less knowledge - is also bigoted won't hurt the message and I believe would drive home the idea of why that behavior is destructive and not welcome here.

Thanks.

Comment: Forget this website; we're making a competitor site without CoC where people ask/answer for monetized tokens.

Comment: If you can monetize the usefulness of the answer, then let me know about this new site.

Answer (score -5):

It's scary and unfair

Let's me explain. It says that we should be good and kind. OKAY.

But, at the same time, this "code of conduct" (that is a rule) put penalties, real penalties.

In the very first lines, it says "... and mutual respect".  How is it mutual respect if we should be kind and the moderation/administration of StackOverflow could punish me because of some vague rules.

I'm not a lawyer but I can see a bad contract, and it is a bad contract.

**I wish to see punishment for both sides!**

[image]
This image is not a joke or sarcasm. It is straight! You are abusing, in the same way, that the character of this cartoon abused of his power.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the legal system shouldn't exist, because all laws are essentially just imposing punishments for arbitrary rules for things that someone decided shouldn't be allowed? Without punishment for misbehavior, the rules become meaningless. Why would someone take time to follow rules if there was no downside to disobeying them?

Comment: I don't understand how this is actually scary in any real world sense. This site is not about the ultimate service of self-expression without penalty or consequence. That's hedonism. 
This site is devoted to the sharing of useful knowledge regarding software development and practices. Anything that doesn't advance that notion should have no place here.
Additionally, how much does it cost you to stay respectful while sharing information? How much information have you gathered from other people? Were you always rude to them?

Comment: Lambs should obey,  moderators must do whatever they are pleased. How is it fair?  People are dumb to accept such rules, it is clear.

The legal system should exist and must be fair, i.e. politicians, cops and citizens must follow it.  I never say that it must be an anarchy.  sheesh.

Answer (score -5):

**Code of Conduct Re: Question Closure?**

May I ask where are the guidelines on Question Closure? I know Stack doesn't want to move towards a forum but some pertinent questions get closed really fast (like hours or even minutes) - users would find said questions useful, maybe the closure period should be extended to say 72hours after being "flagged" or something?

Would it be beneficial to have Code of Conduct mention Question Closure policies? Confused about this bit.

Comment: The code of conduct is about the civility to be applied between users when you are discussing moderation actions. Let's not abuse the CoC to further diminish the useful participation of the [caretakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/578411).

Comment: @rene OK thanks for explaining further.

Comment: I feel that all negative actions (closure, block, hide, delete, downvote etc) have a very harsh psychological consequences and they all  (closure, block, hide, delete, downvote etc) comes within the scope of civility and mutual respect.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused It's a User Experience thing. Like let's say you take Uber, then the driver gives you 2 Stars the first time you ride because you came down from your apartment late. It can be weird because you're like, wait, what? But of course, if you repeatedly do that, it's inconveniencing the driver and you would deserve to be rated that and accept said rating consequences. But for NEW users that's where my (and probably yours) concern lies. And also overall fairness for existing and long-time users overall. Lots for Stack to sort out I reckon.

Answer (score -5):

About the new code of conducts; I am partly welcoming and partly disagree.

The good thing it remembers us to not tell another "lazy" or that type of discriminatory comment, actually the the person who is being pinpointed, does have her/his own problems and own respects which may be difficult to understand for others. Yes, we need to be respectful to everyone. We can hardly have a "respect all, suspect all" view; but we cannot confirm whether someone is intentionally lazy.

Avoid joke is also a good advice, because jokes are usually "indirect" ways  that could delay the convey of actual information, and confuses some people and led to misunderstanding (and simply we can't blame a person if (s)he is unable to crack the hidden meaning of a joke)

But I disagree with the next part; I found 2 big areas in these codes of conduct, are flawed.

ABSENCE OF SEPARATE GUIDELINE FOR USERS WITH AUTHORITATIVE POSITIONS.

**1. The most hurting responses are more often obtained from many reputed or highly qualified users** than newbie users and students, who are unaware about our website structure. Also the hurting behaviour of most newbies differ from hurting behaviour of most experts. So there must be *separate guides* for (1) newbie users and for (2) highly reputed/ highly qualified/ more experienced (high activity for more than 1 years).

There must be more exemption from punishment for newbie users. Particularly the "examples" in that page mostly pinpoints new users. Actually new users feel insecurities and panics with fate of their submitted questions, and also tend to use improper wording, failing to express actual question, and misinterpret others' responses. Also  in this community we commonly use a specific form of language (a new dialect?), otherwise known as highly formal language (As seen in Dilbert comic strip), and many of common people are unaware of this form of language use, that adds up to misinterpretation. So we must have patience and tolerance to gently teach our community guidelines, and we need to be excellent listeners to newbie users.

And similarly there must be separate  guidelines so that experienced users stay alert that they do not show arrogance and **do not use authoritative force**. Also, experienced users should learn to keep questions alive until it reaches an appropriate audience. A downvote without an explanation, and a very early close vote, should be considered as rudeness. Also the so the experienced users, such as moderators and editors, must learn how not to make newbies anxious. Moderators need to be more caring.

AUTISM-SPECTRUM PEOPLE LACK AN INTUITIVE GRASP ON CODE OF CONDUCTS AND SOCIAL NORMS.

**2. The list of unacceptable behaviours: the friendly and unfriendly versions:** will cause cumbersome situation on an **user with autism-spectrum** (such as me); such 'conditions' would be useless because it may be impossible to comprehend what way of saying make people hurt.  So whenever implementing such complex norms (which you can't finish with even several million more examples), you do an injustice for an autism spectrum user (whatever diagnosed or undiagnosed).

The injustice will take place in following way.

- A. I agree, sometimes an action like edits or normal feedbacks could be misinterpreted as rude or deleterious. In such case, please do not keep the norm hidden within only examples. Explicitly mention, "**Please explain if your action is not rude**. Such as if an user express a discomfort seeing the submission edited,  tell the user that an edit is a routine part of a review , which can actually improve the submission, and the original poster can again improve the question"
- B. **Language can only sugarcoat intentions. Language can't change intentions.** We require good intentions,  and we do not need a bad intention in a disguise that is even more harmful than a bad intention without disguise. So we should request people to really have good intentions than disguised language.
- C. **Directness in work environment is important for survival of an autism spectrum person.** Also directness can provide a friendly and simple world for neurotypicals too, directness is a prerequisite for autism spectrum.The problem is two-fold. (1) Unfortunately, in a "normal" conversation the  neurotypicals watches and listens a lot of complex parameters *other than the intended meaning*. So in cases an autism spectrum person aware about only the literal information content; many neurotypicals may mistakenly interpret it as rude, and misunderstands. (where it doesn't mean anything else than the literal information) (2) Neurotypicals, while delivering their turn, often  sugarcoat their message, such as by adding extra words, or telling about something else and expecting the listener will 'teleologically' understand the meaning. But this is a very wrong way of communication with autism-spectrum people because they'll perhaps fail to decipher the metaphor. **Now if you punish  an autism-spectrum person for not being able to sugarcoat the message, it is absolutely ridiculous.** Maybe you don't know how ridiculous it is. It is as ridiculous as to punish an earthworm for not being able to fly.   Take a simple example. **A current example says “Are you speaking English? If so, I can’t tell.”** It is a simple and direct statement, and I fail to figure out why it is offensive. Its simply an user is telling (S)he don't know English well, and is unable to respond to certain request. Now suppose if I wrote **"I can't answer this part of your question because I don't understand the quantum mechanics"... I have to face punishment!** What a hell of injustice.
- D. Even a neurotypical person's talk are misinterpreted in many cases (in real life); and moreover in this global community with members from various cultures and languages, misinterpretations would be very high.
- E.  There are scopes of intentional misuse of these punishments.

I think, a fast action should be taken ONLY if the speech is "clearly offensive" such as hate-speeches, sexual harassments, personal attacks, etc (and I think such level of is rarely reached). In case of comparatively milder situation, (Including my example when a sentence carrying an unintended "neurotypical" gesture but the speaker is unaware of it), and other cases like a mild level of arguments; **an immediate block or immediate punishment would worsen everything**.  Instead they themselves or other users could positively help them to come out of misunderstandings.

Comment: "There must be more exemption from punishment for newbie users" Hmm. Nah. They can already be pretty exempt just by creating a new account. And since punishment starts at "silently deleting comments", escalates to "politely worded mod warning", and only after that starts showing teeth, there's really no call for "exemptions".

Comment: Also, I didn't downvote, but comments to the effect of "please explain downvotes, otherwise they're useless" are never very worthwhile. Votes are useful to indicate sentiment on meta sites or quality judgements on main sites, and that's their primary purpose: that is, allowing moderately senior members to collaborate on informing others which posts should have the most attention paid to them. Feedback to authors, while very handy, is secondary at most.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks very much for explaining. But how can I know "Votes are useful to indicate sentiment on meta sites"? is there any help article explicitely meaning this?

Comment: [What's Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) covers this from a somewhat idealistic standpoint. In practice, meta voting tends to always be at least a little more sentiment-based than main-site voting, although it's most noticeable on feature requests.

Answer (score -6):

The issue I have with the code of conduct is around 2 related things:

1. How vague/specific is my question;
2. Could I have easily googled it;

— because I think this is very presumptive on the part of others ... let me explain.

My question is as specific as I can make it given my current understanding AND my question is as vague or general as it needs to be so that the scope covers everything I want to know AND it’s as vague as it has no other choice in being, given what I don’t know about the subject ... AND IT IS EXTREMELY UNHELPFUL when people tell you what you already know about the fact your question may be a bit vague — ie: they should just help or be quiet.

YES I KNOW there’s a limit to this — ie: you can’t just ask “explain Linux”, BUT I think the line has been drawn a hell of a long way from that part of the sandpit based on my own experience of people’s responses.

ALSO AND MORE IMPORTANTLY — given the capacity to update a question — often a good strategy would be to ask an initial question that might be a little vague, and as the answers start coming in, and you learn, you can modify the post, adding your own comments, and thus for the newbie they get to see the journey of learning, which might help them directly or indirectly by explaining things along the way they hadn’t thought to ask, or which point out the gap in the knowledge which concerns them, and thus helps them resolve their own issue.

So the assumption that such vagueness is always bad, is just plain wrong.

MEANWHILE on the topic of googling, how the hell would anyone know what someone else can or can’t google for? That’s just wrong also ... in order to successfully google a topic, not only have you got to get past googles commercial bias, the lack of sophisticated advanced search function in it, and the fact that you don’t exactly know what you’re searching for ... but you’ve also got to get around what terms to use in the search, and the fact that countless billions of pages exist ( many of which might be too technically complex to understand ) ... so this part of the code of conduct is again counterproductive towards actually helping people ... if you don’t want to help, don’t, but don’t tell them they can’t even ask.

Comment: It sounds like you're choking a bit on the fact that SE sites close questions that could conceivably be answered by someone in a way that could help you — if they believe the answers couldn't help anyone else. This is understandable, but unfortunately this is not a problem with the Code of Conduct: it's part of the fundamental design of the sites. SE is designed to get good answers for lots of people to find and read. It's tough to work out which questions are and aren't going to collect those answers, but that's why closing requires so much site experience.

Comment: That’s not my issue at all, and I’m pretty sure I just stated that fact

Answer (score -15):

The main problem with this code of conduct, that not only the negative comments are expelling the new users.

The voting moral is expelling them, more exactly the attitude of the community expels them. The comments in negative tone are only a maniphestation of this negative attitude.

**I think your idea is essentially bad from the view, that it ignores the voting moral, which is at least so important part of the welcoming-ness of the sites, than the attitude of the comments.**

More clearly: you essentially want to make the negative comments much more seriously punishable. Ok, then people won't comment, they will just vote down (close, del). I don't think that a site where never, nobody says any negative, only it is simply impossible for a newbie to join the community because of the Q/A-ban, or to get an answer to his question because the close votes, would be more welcoming as the current system.

After many years of experience of many sites, my rock solid opinion is that a large part of the most active voters are motivated by an irrational urge to cause so many harm for others, as it is only possible.

These are very hard to track, much harder as to simply suspend productive answerers because they said some negative to crap posts.

I think you are now going to the least resistence, and it won't work.

What I would suggest instead of working on Cyril Northcote Parkinson's [Law of Triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), do this:

Utilize *real* data mining to calculate the *net effect* of users to the site. It is hard, much harder as to simply creating beautiful diagrams and inserting them to strongly upvoted blog entries. You will probably need soft methods, too.

For example, a user casted already terrible mass of downvotes expelled probably a lot of users from the site. But he also helped a lot the site to show its content more attractive to the googlers (suspecting he voted really the bad content down and not every afternoon shoot out his daily 40 "rockets" randomly, just for fun). How can you say, that his net effect is positive or not? You don't say, you are simply ignoring this a whole. Say it, calculate it! You have the voting data, you have the data of the deleted posts and the user activites.

**Build probability models for that, try to model the *behaviors* and the *feelings* of the users with them! Use massively soft models, use AI, use probability networks and Markov-models, and then *predict* the behavior of the induvidual users and their *net effect* to the site, depending on the events what happen to them.**

I am sure, that you don't do it. Why? I don't know, but I suspect. And I suspect that you simply don't trust these advanced methods enough, to base important strategical decisions to them.

Google trusts them. Microsoft trusts them. Ok, they have much more money, but... also you are a medium-sized company in the US. You are still one of the top100 content providers of the world. And you are the only site of the world, which produces mostly better google results if I narrow down the search pattern to you with a site:something.stackexchange.com suffix.

I can't believe that you couldn't pay a small team of data scientists/AI researchers and integrate their work into your software development.

This way will work.

Building yet another committe to write yet another document, it won't.

Comment: *After many years of experience of many sites, my stone hard opinion is that a large part of the most active voters are motivated by an irrational urge to cause so many harm for others, as it is only possible.* Thats a pretty insulting and offensive way to speak about people who spend their highly valued free time to help curate this online resource. I won't r/a flag this, but I strongly urge you to consider removing or at least rewording it.

Comment: @Magisch Saying that it is true or not, I should not write it, it may be a strong argument (if it is enough well reasoned). Simply denying the problem and stating that all the massive downvoters, *all of them without a single exception*, are just good-hearted crusaders helping the site to show its best possible face to the google, well the strength of this "argument" nears zero.

Comment: There are ways to phrase what you want to say without directly insulting people, however.

Comment: @Magisch I can't see any direct insult in the post. Beside that, the essence of the first half of the post is that improvement of the comment attitude is inseparable from the improvement of the voting attitude. I think it is right, however exactly the most massive downers will likely strongly disagree it. They will likely vote this answer down, however they vote my posts always down -> there is no motivation for me to make my posts acceptable for them. I think it is better if I simply say the truth (or what I think is the truth).

Comment: this answer appears to substitute one problem with another. Rudeness is definitely a problem (and always was). But whether "expelling the new users" is a problem is really unclear - I just checked [traffic stats](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) and top 20 sites all show tens or hundreds thousands more visits/day than questions asked. Meaning that even if we assume that all questions are asked by new users, their amount is totally insignificant compared to visits and their contribution to site success is very minor. Whether it goes a bit higher or lower, this won't make much difference

Comment: ...heck even if new users questions would go an order of magnitude higher, it won't really matter because it would still be _thousands / tens thousands_ times less than visits/day. Except for maybe that flood of low quality questions would repel answerers (who contribute content that appeals those who make "visits/day) which in turn would lead to decrease of major success factor (visits). And Stack Exchange would eventually turn into yet another useless Quora / Yahoo Answers

Comment: @gnat Yes, more welcome-ness causes quality decrease, which causes user loss. But also overmoderation causes user loss, particularly if it is often not fair. How can you decide, which is stronger? Do you have any quantitative analysis for that? No. Does the SE have? I think, they have not too much - they seem to favor human micro-management to AI methods. The post tries to focus on that.

Comment: yes, please check [my prior comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/313439?noredirect=1#comment1027163_313439). I started searching for quantitative data as soon as I found that you substituted one problem for another. I thought maybe the other problem you presented somehow correlates to make a substantial impact so I looked for where I can find data to estimate it. I found this data in traffic stats referred in mentioned comment and it suggests that this problem is insignificant. I would be happy to learn if I missed something

Comment: How does more welcomeness decrease quality? Which exact action is being considered as more welcoming that leads to a decrease in the quality of Stack Exchange?

Comment: @gnat You are generating verbal models on not enough data. We could play that you explain some correlation with a strong phylosophical flavor, and then I answer with another correlation with a similarly strong phylosophical flavor. This is what is going on the MSE infinitely long. All of them are only small parts of the big picture. We can't make the whole, because we don't have access to all the data (and processing it correctly is a much bigger work than writing some SEDE queris). We can only infinitely long debate about different small parts of the picture, but it won't worth too much.

Comment: @gnat The focus of the post is a suggestion to the SE to build that whole picture, and use it for the community control (here "control" means as control in "control technology").

Comment: @Andrew The fear of the [deletionists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletionism_and_inclusionism_in_Wikipedia) here is that not expelling the LQ posters will lead to quality decrease. It is obviously so. But having a too high limit leads to a quantity decrease (and many whining). The SE has to balance between them: 1) not allowing the site quality to decrease 2) but trying to expel the possible least users. The essence of the post is to use more advanced, objective methods for that than the current human micromanagement.

Comment: @Andrew check Gnat's [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/313439#comment1027164_313439) comment, I think it is essentially the same answer to your question, but from their view.

Answer (score -15):

IMO, the site feature of down voting questions and answers should just be removed completely.  It's never really helpful and only fosters a negative and elitist sentiment. Just let us like(upvote) correct or exceptional questions and responses.

If the intention is to filter out the noise and riff raff, this would be better served with a basic comment flag feature that mods would be alerted about and deal with themselves.

Comment: Do that, and the whole network will go to pot.  Downvoting is a primary curation capability, one that helps filter the good stuff from the bad.

Comment: Being able to flag a comment would enable the same type of curation capability and filtering.  Being able to still upvote would facilitate the same kind of ranking/reward system the site has now.

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  All it does is push the decision onto someone else, overburdening them.  Upvotes without downvotes just removes half of the quality metric.

Comment: Abuse of the downvote feature is obviously an issue with many members on the site.  Personally, I would never downvote an honest attempt at an answer. As long as the best answers float to the top, and bad ones fall to the bottom I don't see what the difference would be.  The fact is this site can be self-curated without the downvote feature.  Some folks just enjoy having the ability to express negative sentiment toward a response.  That is, in addition to the comment section.

Comment: Citation needed.  I don't believe they're being abused.  Show evidence that they are.

Comment: I think the number of answers that suggest revamping the downvoting provides good context for this, and the site's seeming inability to even discuss changes to downvoting would also back up that up as well.

There are no guidelines on how to cast a downvote. It is often for trivial reasons, or over-zealous mods.

A large part of the  Stack Exchange community is calling for a revamp to welcomeness and entrenched users often ignore the issue, despite the relevance of the site declining because of the aggressive exclusiveness of the site.

Comment: @Andrew The reason people are unwilling to discuss this is because it's been brought up in one form or another at least once a week for the past 9 years. Anyone suggesting such a thing could easily find 50+ topics where their idea has been picked apart and voted on by the community already. People aren't reflexively downvoting the idea, they're reflexively downvoting the lack of effort to look for similar suggestions before making them.

Comment: Also citation needed that a admittedly not trivial amount of people who don't research before posting == a large amount.

Comment: @Andrew As always, citation needed.  You're also equating downvoting, which is a curation activity, with welcoming, which is an entirely separate issue.  Correlating them won't get you much traction here, as they aren't meant to be the same thing.

Comment: @Magisch, are you implying that the existence of people who disagree with your opinion should be considered reason to not post your opinion?  I hope that's not what you're asserting here.  I started my post with IMO for a reason and I doubt any amount of searching will change the reason for my post.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm still waiting for you to provide citations for the assertions you've already made. Here's your homework assignment:"Correlating them won't get you much traction here," please provide evidence or citation to support this statement you made about the community.

Comment: Your evidence: The votes on your proposal here.  I'm still waiting on you to provide evidence of your statement.  Time to show us the money.

Comment: @webnetweaver No, I mean that if you have an idea, you should check if your idea is at all novel over the 200 other threads of almost exactly the same idea. And if it's not, what makes you think the outcome of the discussion will be different then the last 10 times it's been discussed? If you made this as a feature-request tagged question, it'd be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Magisch I can understand what you mean but Im not looking to sway or persuade here.  I know people are firmly entrenched in their thoughts about this because they have expressed it...which is what I'm doing here...expressing my thoughts.  No delusion of novelty here and no delusion or expectation of anything different than the response I've received.

Comment: @fbueckert I believe Magisch can direct you to approximately 200 other threads with comments expressing the thoughts I'm expressing here to the point where this is identified quickly as a duplicate. You guys should get together and share notes  :)

Comment: Ah, so you don't have anything.  Got it.  That means your statement provides nothing to seriously weigh and consider.  To that end, I'm going to stop engaging now.

Comment: @fbueckert, I am not correlating downvote with being 'welcoming.' I am a strong believer that the process can be reviewed as a way to both uphold the standards of quality while being welcoming. ie... you can have your downvote and find a way to be welcoming or informative. They are not mutually exclusive and treating the downvote as a means to ensure standards without communicating the context behind the downvote is ultimately why many people find this site so frustrating and feckless