# Does the new code of conduct still leave room for decent humor?

Tags: discussion, answers, offensive

I've illustrated a recent answer for a more or less useless question with a little picture after the OP was asking back:

[const literal versus const function as rvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455547/1413395) (please check the link regarding updates vs the taken screenshot!)

[image]

Regarding the overworked codes of conduct, would such be considered harmful, offensive or belittling in any direction?

After the OP asked back in comments, I just felt giving an illustration might just be the shortest<sup>1</sup> and friendliest way for responding, and taking on their concerns.

---

TBH: In a workplace review situation I'd probably not draw that picture, it would more go like

- Please don't do that. It's blatantly wrong, and at best our CI systems static analysis will bail out  on your commit with an error.
- Your code isn't reliable, you do assumptions about specific behavior, regarding the memory layout and number representation which is *compiler* and / or *OS* dependent
- Please explain in depth why you wrote that code as is and what do you expect to achieve.

Well even there I'd be tempted to draw that in regard of how often such is seen with the OP's code.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Well, it took some efforts finding the appropriate pic, load it to Gimp, and put my remarks. I still believe it was worth it, than writing a very long and elaborate paragraph.</sub>

Comment: This looks harmless, but more specifically, I don't see how this belittles or insults the original poster, but rather it makes slight humor pointed at the question itself.

Comment: @hover it looks harmless, yes. But there's a lotta heat underneath. At the SO [tag:c++] tag we meet such questions in a quite recurring manner (I believe it's a similar thing with Java). In the end, it's how the OP be it the current one or a future researcher sees themselves represented in the picture.

Comment: Also earlier comments of mine regarding the nature of UB were considered rude or abusive, and contributed to my recent ban.

Comment: UB questions seem to, too often,generate long strings of comments that are just about the most annoying, depressing and fruitless exchanges on SO.  OP's will just keep going, demanding a deeper explanation, and get ratty when the are refused one or told 'trace it through with your own debugger on your own system for find out more about what is happening to you':(    Another case for one comment only: 'pointer x is uninitialized - undefined behaviour', (or array index OOB, or whatever flavour of UB).  with down and close votes..Ignore any plaintive demands folllowing..

Comment: Most of the annoying UB are homework anyway.  Just the simplest 'xxxxx is undefined behaviour' is likely to set off the OP on an unwelcoming death-spiral because their homework assignment says 'YOU MUST PROVIDE FULL EXPLANATIONS FOR YOUR ANSWERS', in bold, across the top.  So, they go on, and on, and on, trying to get a comprehensive, hand-inable, explanation for something that cannot be explained:(

Comment: ..on top of which, it's 'Homework Sunday' tomorrow:(

Comment: @MartinJames: Then there's a possible obvious solution -- to find or *create* a canonical question and answer, and use it to close the UB question as a duplicate. No need for long discussions, but instead refer to the extensive and comprehensive discussion in the answer used to close the question.

Comment: The new code of conduct deems anything offensive if *someone* finds it offensive, which means they would eventually have to delete everything the whole site.

Answer (score 6):

[We hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

On the other hand, I'm pretty guilty of injecting humor into posts - both organically ([here](https://superuser.com/a/269324/10165)) and with the occational use of [memes](https://superuser.com/questions/1007179/connect-two-usb-devices-to-one-port/1007211#1007211). If humour is decent, not hurtful and on topic, sometimes it can get a pass.

I don't think anyone in particular wants to be the fun police (tm) and an omnibus rule against it sounds potentially prone to abuse.

I've personally gone for three independent sets of criteria in deciding on whether to do something similar.

- Does it add to the *impact* of the answer? If it adds to its substance, it would be fine.
- Does it <strike>have boromir</strike> actually have any relevance to the question?
- Is someone actually offended by the content (as opposed to the mere fact that it's funny)? Admittedly, if flagged I leave it for other mods to handle, or if there's a polite request as opposed to "No. MEMES BAD!"

> TBH: In a workplace review situation I'd probably not draw that picture

And this is an important point here. For most part, I feel that informal "workplace" rules are a good baseline. Explain exactly as you would if a young padawan wanted your advice at a water fountain. The second option especially feels like it reflects the same point the image does, so much more concisely. I, for one, would paraphrase LOTR if I was explaining things to a co-worker I figured would get it.

Comment: It looks a like a part of your quote got cut off.

Comment: naw - I actually should have cut off more

Comment: I see a thick layer of dust on Jeff Atwood's "We hate fun" which exclusively deals with questions....