# Linking to /?lastactivity breaks when that activity is on second or greater page

Tags: bug, answers, hyperlinks, last-activity

When viewing posts by recently active, the last action can generally be linked to directly by clicking the "answered/modified" link. For example, the "answered 5 hours ago" text circled here:

[image: Question from the home page with the text "answered 5 hours ago" circled]

Clicking this takes you to the link `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review/?lastactivity`

It seems, however, when that `/?lastactivity` (either answered or modified) occurs somewhere other than the first page of answers, linking directly to the post fails and, instead, links to the question itself. This makes finding the recent activity difficult, particularly when there are many pages of answers. Yes, I can sort the answers by active but not everyone realizes that's an option.

I've reproduced this on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), so it's not an MSE-specific issue nor is it apparently related to the responsive layout. I've also seen this behavior on answers that were answered, edited, or deleted.

---

#### To reproduce:

1. Find a question on the Home or Questions/Active page with >30 answers.
2. Click on the last activity link next to the username of the person who performed that action

   - Using PPCG questions with >60 answers that are newly answered is the most likely to consistently be a good choice as new answers to questions with many existing answers are unlikely to have surfaced above the latter page/s.
3. See that the end result is identical to loading the question link/does not take you to the answer.

I suppose that it's possible there isn't a way to fix this but, if there is, it'd be nice to have.

Comment: consider testing this in "incognito" mode and with different browser. I suggest this because I experience somewhat similar issue, but this happens only on Firefox and only in logged in mode while things work correctly in Chrome and in incognito mode in FF

Comment: @gnat just tested it in Chrome, both logged in and incognito, still fails.

Comment: This seems to have been caused by [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313428/why-did-the-format-of-full-form-urls-to-answers-change).

Comment: As a test, I tried manually changing the URL to the old form of full-form link, and it properly changed the page and linked to the answer. So it was indeed caused by the above change.