# Answer links have become broken for multi-page questions

Tags: bug, internal-links

Answer links have become broken for multi-page questions.

[`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/313439`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/313439) or 
[`https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313439`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313439) should go to peterh's answer. However, it's on the second page (in the "votes" view), but only the first page is rendered, so I just see the question.

This used to work.

Reproduced in Chrome Stable 67, logged in or logged out.

Comment: Oh, eesh... this seems like it's related to my question from a few days ago: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313288/linking-to-lastactivity-breaks-when-that-activity-is-on-second-or-greater-page ... Not a dupe but probably similar/related issue.

Comment: @Catija Ah, missed that one! Yeah, looks like the same cause.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog If you're going to close this as a dupe, consider changing your question from `support` to a `bug`. I'm not asking for an answer, I'm asking for a fix.

Comment: Added the [tag:bug] tag.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Thanks. Duped.